# How to repair/restore after 'sudo chmod / 777'?

Tags: 10.04, boot, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What if I accidently run command chmod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidently-run-command-chmod)

I changed file permissions recursively on the root directory '/' with `sudo chmod / 777 -R` and after that i run "save mode" and i was changed main directories like a sys, boot, root , etc using (`sudo chmod 440 /etc -R`) etc  and after that can't boot system because many of process don't have permissions.

Please help.

Comment: ouch...good luck sir, I would reinstall and copy config file contents/documents...you might be able to reinstall and diff all files on the new drive to the old drive...

Comment: @aking1012: this should be an answer (maybe a bit more elaborate).

Comment: @Marcin: hope you have a good backup

Comment: What was the reason for doing this?

Comment: @RolandTaylor there never is a reason, it's always a mistake :P

Comment: See also [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/221447/how-to-repair-restore-ubuntu-10-04-after-sudo-chmod-777)

Comment: No reason , it was mistake. 
Thx for yours answers.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to reinstall.