# What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I accidently ran

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /
```

instead of

```
sudo chmod 755 -R ./
```

I stopped it after a few seconds, but now I'm starting to have problems. For example, `sudo` isn't working anymore:

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

How can I revert permissions back?

Comment: oh dear... `sudo` means, that you have **think twice** what you will do!

Comment: The easiest is to reinstall. Put the LiveCD/USB, and at the screen where it asks you to partition your disk, it should give you the option to `Upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.04`. Accept this option, and it will effectively re-install Ubuntu for you, in the most painless way.

Comment: @user4124, I tried, no effect

Comment: Just now you have learned a lesson. You don't need to write `/` in the end of directory name to specify the directory as a target. It's a *bad habit*, don't do it, **never**! The `.` is by itself valid directory name, there is no need to append `/` to it. If everyone followed this rule, then very much mistyped `sudo` operations would have no effect on the root directory, so no harm would've been done to their systems. Don't do it!

Comment: @ulidtko oh great! So `.` is the same as `./`? I'll learn it :)

Comment: @fl00r, yes. It's a directory name which means this, or "current" directory. `cd .`, for example, does nothing. `ls .` is the same as `ls`. Also, the `..` is a directory name which means "the parent of `.`", and you probably knew it already.

Comment: @ulidtko: There is an exception to not using `/` at the end. If you want to do pathname expansion for directories only. Example of listing directories inside the current directory: `echo */`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover from chmod -R a-wrx / command?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265080/how-can-i-recover-from-chmod-r-a-wrx-command)

Comment: @Braiam I am curious why this question is a duplicate and not vice versa?

Comment: @fl00r the other has better answers.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive

Comment: *Any* command that starts with `sudo` should have a thirty second delay between finishing the typing and hitting `ENTER` - that gives ample opportunity to check and check and check again. `sudo` is the chainsaw in your toolkit. Very handy but, if you get it wrong, you'll lose a limb :-)

Comment: @ulidtko you're wrong. There is a difference: _e.g._ if a path ends in a symlink, `ls -ld /path/to/your/symlink` will say about symlink, while `ls -ld /path/to/your/symlink/` will actually dereference the symlink and say about the directory — or give an error that the target is not a directory. So sometimes you _must_ append a trailing `/` after the path.

Comment: @Ruslan I don't care. You're talking me (known) corner cases, I'm talking you **habit**.

Comment: @ulidtko [You said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc#comment47905_43621), "It's a *bad habit*, don't do it, **never**!" The only possible way to interpret "never," there, is as saying there are *no circumstances ever* when one should do it. A single corner case is enough to falsify that claim. But even the much weaker suggestion to *prefer* omitting a trailing `/` would be **extremely questionable**, as there are *common* cases where omitting it *causes* data loss, e.g., `cp file dir` but it turns out `dir` was a file.

Comment: I'm really surprised that I haven't done this by now.

Comment: What I find most fascinating about this is that if your intent to _add_ or _remove_ a specific bit in the file mode, the mnemonic file modes (`rwxX` etc) would have been your friend with `+` and `-`. It seems that the greybeard "wisdom" of using octal file modes to effectively _re-set_ the file mode persists even when modern and fine-grained alternatives exist. Oh well.

Comment: I actually fixed a similar issue easily by booting into single user mode. This can be done by interrupting the boot and editing the boot sequence in GRUB and placing an `s` at the end of the line that begins with `linux` (this line dictates kernel instruction). If there hasn't been a root password manually set, this will give you a root shell. From the shell you can correct your mistake by assigning the correct permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set myself as owner of /etc with chown command now getting all kinds of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300641/set-myself-as-owner-of-etc-with-chown-command-now-getting-all-kinds-of-errors)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In short: **you can't, reinstall your system.**

I mean, Posix permissions are used and relied on heavily; there's a multitude of places in the filesystem where wrong permissions would break the OS (SUID flags) or even worse, make it exposed security-wise (`/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`) while it appears to be working OK.

Hence, such a recovery is hard to do properly. Miss *one thing* — and you screw it up. You *already* screwed up your `sudo chmod` command (if that's *your friend* rather than you, she might as well learn some Linux lesson, too) — and that's a very simple of a command. Proper recovery would demand way more commands and way more vigilance. Even if you use someone's script.

So trust me, just reinstall. It's a safe bet and guaranteed to keep you out of trouble.

---

Finally, some tips relevant here.

First: reinstalls will be less painful if you [setup your `/home` on a separate partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition) next time. Actually, they will be a breeze.

Second: consider doing *crazy Linux science* in a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) like the VirtualBox, and do your snapshots.

Third: `chmod -R .` works. A dot by itself `.` is valid directory name. There's no real need to append that slash. You could've avoided the catastrophic risk of skipping the dot entrirely;
mere `chmod: missing operand after ‘755’` VS a ruined system.

Comment: Ahhh :) so sad.

Comment: Well you *could* by getting all the permissions for every file from another system, but doing this is so much work that it'd probably be easier and safer just to reinstall.

Comment: And don't be sad! *With great power comes great responsibility*

Comment: Yeah I just destroyed my laptop with this...  Amazing how you can easily destroy a linux based machine.

Comment: @amanuel2 with great power comes great responsibility. Watch what you type; `sudo` means you have to check twice.

Comment: Will a `do-release-upgrade` help?

Comment: You can keep your home directory if you install "without formatting".

Answer (score 30):

I wrote and have been using for several years a couple of Ruby scripts to `rsync` permissions and ownership. Script `get-filesystem-acl` collects all the information by recursively traversing all the files and puts it all into the file `.acl`. Script `.acl-restore` will read `.acl` and apply all the `chown`'s and `chmod`'s.

You can run `get-filesystem-acl` on a similar Ubuntu installation and then copy over the `.acl` file to your chmod-damaged box, put `.acl` and `.acl-restore` in /, and run `.acl-restore`.

You will need to have root so fix your `sudo` as Marco Ceppi suggested.

I can generate and give you the `.acl` file for my Ubuntu.

#### `get-filesystem-acl`

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/ruby

RM   = "/bin/rm"
SORT = "/usr/bin/sort"
TMP  = "/tmp/get_acl_#{Time.now.to_i}_#{rand * 899 + 100}"

require 'find'

IGNORE = [".git"]

def numeric2human(m)
  return sprintf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",
            (m & 0400 == 0 ? ?- : ?r),
            (m & 0200 == 0 ? ?- : ?w),
            (m & 0100 == 0 ? (m & 04000 == 0 ? ?- : ?S) :
                             (m & 04000 == 0 ? ?x : ?s)),
            (m & 0040 == 0 ? ?- : ?r),
            (m & 0020 == 0 ? ?- : ?w),
            (m & 0010 == 0 ? (m & 02000 == 0 ? ?- : ?S) :
                             (m & 02000 == 0 ? ?x : ?s)),
            (m & 0004 == 0 ? ?- : ?r),
            (m & 0002 == 0 ? ?- : ?w),
            (m & 0001 == 0 ? (m & 01000 == 0 ? ?- : ?T) :
                             (m & 01000 == 0 ? ?x : ?t)))
end


File.open(TMP, "w") do |acl_file|

  # TODO: Instead of the current dir, find the .git dir, which could be
  #       the same or outside of the current dir
  Find.find(".") do |path|

    next if IGNORE.collect {|ig| !!(path[2..-1] =~ /\A#{ig}/)}.include? true
    next if File.symlink?(path)

    stat = File.lstat(path)
    group_id = stat.gid
    rules    = "#{type}#{numeric2human(stat.mode)}" 

    acl_file.puts "#{path} #{rules} #{owner_id} #{group_id}"
  end
end

`#{SORT} #{TMP} > .acl`
`#{RM}   #{TMP}`
```

#### `.acl-restore`

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# This script will only work with .acl_ids

# Restore from...
FROM  = ".acl"

MKDIR = "/bin/mkdir"
CHMOD = "/bin/chmod"
CHOWN = "/bin/chown"
known_content_missing = false


def numeric2human(m)
  return sprintf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",
            (m & 0400 == 0 ? ?- : ?r),
            (m & 0200 == 0 ? ?- : ?w),
            (m & 0100 == 0 ? (m & 04000 == 0 ? ?- : ?S) :
                             (m & 04000 == 0 ? ?x : ?s)),
            (m & 0040 == 0 ? ?- : ?r),
            (m & 0020 == 0 ? ?- : ?w),
            (m & 0010 == 0 ? (m & 02000 == 0 ? ?- : ?S) :
                             (m & 02000 == 0 ? ?x : ?s)),
            (m & 0004 == 0 ? ?- : ?r),
            (m & 0002 == 0 ? ?- : ?w),
            (m & 0001 == 0 ? (m & 01000 == 0 ? ?- : ?T) :
                             (m & 01000 == 0 ? ?x : ?t)))
end

def human2chmod(mode)
  raise unless mode =~ /([r-][w-][xtsTS-])([r-][w-][xtsTS-])([r-][w-][xtsTS-])/
  triple = [$1, $2, $3]
  u,g,o = triple.collect do |i|
    i.sub('s', 'sx').sub('t', 'tx').downcase.gsub('-', '')
  end

  return "u=#{u},g=#{g},o=#{o}" 
end



File.open(FROM).each do |acl|
  raise unless acl =~ /\A(([^ ]*? )+)([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)\Z/
  path, rules, owner_id, group_id = $1, $3, $4, $5
  path = path.strip
  owner_id = owner_id.to_i
  group_id = group_id.to_i

  if !File.exists?(path) and !File.symlink?(path)
    if rules =~ /\Ad/
      STDERR.puts "Restoring a missing directory: #{path}"
      STDERR.puts "Probably it was an empty directory. Git goes not track them."
      `#{MKDIR} -p '#{path}'` # Creating the any parents
    else
      known_content_missing = true
      STDERR.puts "ERROR: ACL is listed but the file is missing: #{path}"
      next
    end
  end

  s = File.lstat(path)
  t = s.ftype[0..0].sub('f', '-') # Single character for the file type
                                  # But a "-" istead of "f"

  # Actual, but not neccesarely Desired 
  actual_rules    = "#{t}#{numeric2human(s.mode)}"
  actual_owner_id = s.uid 
  actual_group_id = s.gid 

  unless [actual_rules, actual_owner_id, actual_group_id] ==
    [rules, owner_id, group_id]

    chmod_argument = human2chmod(rules)

    # Debug
    #p chmod_argument
    #p s.mode

    ## Verbose
    puts path
    puts "Wrong: #{[actual_rules, actual_owner_id, actual_group_id].inspect}"
    puts "Fixed: #{[rules, owner_id, group_id].inspect}"
    `#{CHMOD} #{chmod_argument} '#{path}'`

    #puts
  end

end

if known_content_missing
  STDERR.puts "-" * 80 
  STDERR.puts "Some files that are listed in #{FROM.inspect} are missing in " +
              "the current directory."
  STDERR.puts
  STDERR.puts "Is #{FROM.inspect} outdated?"
  STDERR.puts "(Try retrograding the current directory to an earlier version)"
  STDERR.puts
  STDERR.puts "Or is the current directory incomplete?"
  STDERR.puts "(Try to recover the current directory)"
  STDERR.puts "-" * 80 
end
```

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04. But I've reinstalled it already. Thanks!

Comment: your script fails as `owner_id` is undefined

Comment: kinda an overkill... find does that quite nicely: `find SOME_DIR -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > saved_permission`

Answer (score 14):

In long: you can. You'll need to mount the the file system from the a Live CD and begin reverting the permissions in the appropriate places. At a minimum to get sudo back you'll want to run `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo` while in the LiveCD session - that will fix the must be setuid root.

However, it would likely be easier to simply reinstall the system.

Answer (score 5):

###### How to prevent future accidents

All answers here focus (predictably) on restoring the system to a working state. But no answer focuses on how to better prevent a similar accident in the future.

To completely prevent accidents like this in the future, add the following to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_aliases`) file:

```
# set Safetynets
alias sudo='sudo '    # This allows sudo to run aliases
alias chmod='chmod --preserve-root'
alias chown='chown --preserve-root'
alias chgrp='chgrp --preserve-root'
```

Also, make sure the same contents are inside the `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_aliases`) file of the `root` user as well (else it doesn't matter!).

In this way, you CAN NOT use these commands (even as `root`) recursively on the root filesystem.

###### Adding this to `~/.bashrc`

Add the following line to your own `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo "alias sudo='sudo '    # This allows sudo to run aliases" >> ~/.bashrc
```

An easy way to add lines to roots `~/.bashrc` is to use a "heredoc". First switch to the root user:

```
sudo -s
```

Then run the following text block:

```
cat << EOT >> ~/.bashrc

# set Safetynets
alias sudo='sudo '    # This allows sudo to run aliases
alias chmod='chmod --preserve-root'
alias chown='chown --preserve-root'
alias chgrp='chgrp --preserve-root'
EOT
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions!

Comment: Can you also explain how to add these commands to the .bashrc file?

Answer (score 4):

I would try to reinstall all packages with `apt-get install --reinstall`, possibly using the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep install` to get a list of them.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea but you'd need to exclude things that are automatically installed or you'd permanently end up with those packages (even if you removed the dependant packages)... But then they wouldn't get reinstalled. Tough one. Perhaps getting a list of the automatic packages first, then reinstall *every* package then go through the list of autos, re-marking them as auto.

Comment: @Oli - wouldn't (some of) that be solved by running `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: @Wilf No - `autoremove` only removes packages that you haven't installed manually.

Comment: There exist `apt-mark auto $pkg`/`apt-mark manual $pkg` which allow you to modify the status of "manually installed/autoinstalled" per-package.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I haven't tested this (so use at your own risk), but it still might work. I Will test this in a virtual machine when I get the chance to:

First, in a still working system, I did the following to get all file permissions in a list, skipping the `/home/` directory:

```
sudo find / -not -path /home -printf "%m:%p\0" > /tmp/fileper.log
```

This will print the permissions and file name for each file or directory on the system, followed by a `\0` character (this is needed later on to deal with weird file names such as those containing newlines).

Then, on a system where the file permissions have been compromised:

```
while IFS=: read -r -d '' perm file; do  
    chmod "$perm" "$file"
done < /tmp/fileper.log
```

This will read each line of `fileper.log`, saving the permissions as`$perm` and the file name as `$file` and then will set the file (or directory's) permissions to whatever was listed in the `fileper.log`

---

A few things to note here:

- While outputting to the file: `/tmp/fileper.log`, you might be listing custom settings, and proc, etc.
- you might not be able to boot, or run commands,

What I would suggest is boot up a LiveCD with the Linux version you have on your disk, run the command, modify the path to where you have the local disk mounted, and run the second command!

---

I have tested that when booted from an Ubuntu CD/USB, I can choose not to format disk, meaning it will replace everything in the `/` directory, *BUT* skip the `/home/` directory. Meaning your users will have the configuration of apps/DATA(Music,Video,Documents) still intact. And by replacing the system files, the `chmod` is set to there proper number.

Comment: Why `chmod $(echo $LINE)` instead of just `chmod $LINE`? Also, you can use just `find` without `stat`: `find … -printf "%#m %p\n"`. Better yet, you can create the entire command: `find … -printf "chmod %#m %p\n"`, then execute the file as a script.

Comment: The find line isn't working as it is, it should be `michael@NEXUS-TWO:~$ sudo find / -name '*' -exec stat -c "%a %n" {} \; >> /tmp/fileper.log` but then as well it runs over `/proc` and some other places which you might not want in your list.

Comment: @muru wrote this in the middle of the night. Will edit the code...

Comment: Not able to test, will rely on user input

Answer (score 4):

You can try restoring permissions with `apt-get`.

If you can not run these commands with sudo you may need to boot to recovery mode and run them as root.

For booting to recovery mode see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode.

From http://hyperlogos.org/page/Restoring-Permissions-Debian-System

Note: This was originally posted on the Ubuntu Forums but I can not find the original post.

Try, in order,

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1`
```

If that fails:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 | egrep -v '(package1|package2)'`
```

And finally, as a last resort,

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 | xargs apt-get --reinstall -y --force-yes install
```

Using apt-get

Here's the relevant snip, EDITED FOR CORRECTNESS and reformatted:

> ```
> sudo apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1`
> ```
>
> Let's say you get messages about some packages that can't be reinstalled, and the command fails. Here's one way to fix it by skipping the packages in question:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 | egrep -v '(package1|package2)'`
> ```
>
> And finally, if you should somehow have so many things installed that the above command fails saying your argument list is too long, here's the fix, which will run apt-get many more times than you might like:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 | xargs apt-get --reinstall -y --force-yes install
> ```
>
> Note the `-y` and `--force-yes` options, which will stop `apt-get` from prompting you over and over again. These are always fun options, if you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Unfortunately this made things worse for me, by braking the system settings. I cannot access Display anymore... Reinstall is on its way it seems

Comment: I thought --reinstall wouldn't replace any settings unless you included a flag to force replace config files?

Answer (score 3):

(I know I shouldn't comment in an answer, but not enough reputation to comment.)

blade19899's answer worked for me except for symlinks. E.g. it applied 755 to /bin/bash, but then applied 777 to the symlink /bin/rbash, effectively 777-ing /bin/bash.

As I already had the fileper.log file, I just modified the destination-end command:

```
while IFS=: read -r -d '' perm file; do  
    if [[ ! -L "$file" ]]; then    
        chmod "$perm" "$file"
    fi
done < /tmp/fileper.log
```

Comment: If you have a backup of permissions, why not just make a full backup and restore it when needed? That would save you in case of any command run accidentally, not just `chmod`.

Comment: > `... effectively 777-ing /bin/bash` — nope; that's not how it works. Are you saying I can replace `/usr/bin/apt` with my own thing *as a non-root user*, just by writing to it through a 777 symlink? :) Exercise some critical thinking; symlinks can't, and don't, work that way. 777 permissions for symlinks are common and normal.

Answer (score 2):

There is a closed question (with a great answer) as duplicate of this one from:

- [Set myself as owner of /etc with chown command now getting all kinds of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300641/set-myself-as-owner-of-etc-with-chown-command-now-getting-all-kinds-of-errors/884657)

As such I will give [Terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) the credit but here is my own answer based his.

During development of a new script, the variable  `$TMP_DIRECTORY/` had unexpected result of `/`. This was followed by `chmod 700` and `chown -R $UDO_USER` pointing to `$TMP_DIRECTORY` which was really `/`.

System slowly crashed and burned. After that it would not reboot. Everyone screams "YOU MUST REINSTALL" but that means loosing years of work. This script is a variation of Terdon's answer:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then # root powers needed to call this script
    echo >&2 "$0 must be called with sudo powers"
    exit 1
fi

# Parameters blank?
[[ $1 == "" ]] && echo "Parm 1 must be source directory" && exit 1
[[ $2 == "" ]] && echo "Parm 2 must be target directory" && exit 1

# Parameters valid directories?
[[ ! -d "$1" ]] && echo "Parm 1 must be a directory" && exit 1
[[ ! -d "$2" ]] && echo "Parm 2 must be a directory" && exit 1
# [[ ! "$2" == "/mnt/"* ]] && echo "Parm 2 must start with /mnt/..." && exit 1

# shopt -s globstar     # From original
shopt -s dotglob
liveSystem="$1"
deadSystem="$2"

# Parameters must end in same subdirectory
[[ "${liveSystem##*/}" != "${deadSystem##*/}" ]] && \
    echo "subdirectory ${liveSystem##*/} not same as ${deadSystem##*/}" && \
    exit 1

cd "$deadsystem"
Count=0
NoRef=0
one() {
    path="$1"
    MountlessPath="${path##*$deadSystem/}"
    if [ -e "$liveSystem/$MountlessPath" ] ; then
        echo chown --reference "$liveSystem/$MountlessPath" "$path"
        echo chmod --reference "$liveSystem/$MountlessPath" "$path"
        (( Count++ ))
    else
        echo "No reference for: $path"
        (( NoRef++ ))
    fi
}

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654041/loop-through-all-files-in-a-directory-and-subdirectories-using-bash
# Note typo "If" instead of "if" in above link
recurse() {
  path="$1"
  if [ -d "$path" ] ; then
#     echo "Path: $path"
     one "$path"            # Enhancement: chown of directories too
     for i in "$path/"* # "$path/."* # Enhancement: do hidden directories
     do
        # Skip over .. which gives endless loop
        [[ "$path" == *".cache/speech-dispatcher"* ]] && continue
        [[ "$path" == *"/usr/bin/X11"* ]] && continue
        BaseName=${path##*/}
        [[ "${#BaseName}" -gt 300 ]] && continue
#        [[ ${#BaseName[@]} -gt 1 ]] && continue
#        echo BaseName: $BaseName
#        [[ $BaseName == ".." || $BaseName == "*" ]] && continue
        recurse "$i"
     done
# Original code selected only files but we want links too
#  elif [ -f "$path" ] ; then
  else
    [ ! -f "$path" ] && printf "Not a file -> "
    one "$path"
  fi
}

recurse "$deadSystem"

echo "========================================================================"
echo "$Count references found for chown command to process"
echo "$NoRef files, directories and links, etc. could not be processed"
# From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/can-scp-create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist/193372?noredirect=1#comment1111576_193372
# Original didn't have much luck?
#for file in **/*; do 
#    [ -e "$liveSystem/$file" ] &&
#        echo sudo chown --reference "$liveSystem/$file" "$file"
#done
```

When running the script with `$ sudo reset-owner /mnt/old/var /var | grep "No reference"` the tail end says this:

```bash
Not a file -> No reference for: /var/tmp/systemd-private-fdbc599820b645f4a461404675af3b5d-rtkit-daemon.service-jvV8tG/tmp/*
No reference for: /var/tmp/systemd-private-fdbc599820b645f4a461404675af3b5d-systemd-timesyncd.service-vmgqTh
No reference for: /var/tmp/systemd-private-fdbc599820b645f4a461404675af3b5d-systemd-timesyncd.service-vmgqTh/tmp
Not a file -> No reference for: /var/tmp/systemd-private-fdbc599820b645f4a461404675af3b5d-systemd-timesyncd.service-vmgqTh/tmp/*
No reference for: /var/tmp/uefi.dat
No reference for: /var/tmp/uefi.dsl
========================================================================
12369 references found for chown command to process
7676 files, directories and links, etc. could not be processed
```

As daunting as it seems it only took an hour to work it all out. By the time I was done I was left with this:

```bash
$ sudo reset-owner /mnt/old/var /var | grep "No reference" | grep -v /var/tmp/ | grep -v /var/spool/ | grep -v '\/\*' | grep -v /var/run | grep -v /unattended | grep -v /upstart | grep -v /log/journal | grep -v /log/pm | grep -v /log/cron | grep -v /log/dpkg | grep -v /log/apt | grep -v /log/altern | grep -v /lib/u | grep -v /lib/systemd | grep -v /lib/snapd | grep -v /lib/shim | grep -v /lib/NetworkManager | grep -v /lib/lightdm | grep -v /lib/initram | grep -v /lib/dpkg | grep -v /lib/doc-base | grep -v /var/lib/dkms | grep -v /lib/blue | grep -v /lib/binfmts | grep -v /lib/apt | grep -v /lib/app-info | grep -v /lib/Accounts | grep -v /var/crash | grep -v /var/cache
No reference for: /var
No reference for: /var/lib/flashplugin-installer
No reference for: /var/lib/gems
No reference for: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0
No reference for: /var/lib/git
No reference for: /var/lib/tlp/rfkill-saved
```

Answer (score 0):

For packages, the easiest, fastest, and more stable option that I know of is this Aptitude command below.

In summary, this command automatically restore a package permissions to their default. Including both all its default folder(s) & file(s). The end result is as if the package was freshly installed for the first time with its default permission. While at the same time keeping any already existing configuration file(s).

## Three Steps

### Step 1

Using Terminal/Console, connect into the appropriate Linux user account. This is important because in both steps 2 & 3 below all commands will be executed as this user.

### Step 2

If not already done, using Terminal execute this command to install Sudo

```
apt install sudo
```

Note: For those not familiar with Sudo, allow a Linux user(s) limited super user privileges

If not already done, using Terminal execute this command to install Aptitude

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Note: For those not familiar with Aptitude, it is a package manager. Which is similar to Apt. Aptitude has more functionality than Apt. Aptitude includes both an interactive UI and a text-only interface/CLI. In comparison, Apt lacks an interactive UI. Aptitude is a high-level package manager while Apt is lower-level package manager.

### Step 3

Choose **one** of the four options below. Which will reset the package permissions to their default. And keep the package(s) configuration:

#### Option 1: ONE package. WITHOUT Backport.

- Format: `sudo aptitude reinstall <PACKAGE NAME>`
- Example: `sudo aptitude reinstall jami`

#### Option 2: ALL packages. WITHOUT Backport.

- Example: `sudo aptitude reinstall '~i'`

Note

- This option above will both reinstall ALL already installed packages and reset their permissions to their default. Including your operating system (OS). Before executing this command, it is suggested to complete the appropriate actions. Such as, but not limited to, create a backup, check that you have enough available locale storage. Time needed for this command is similar to installing a new OS.

#### Option 3: ONE package. WITH Backport.

- Format: `sudo aptitude -t <CODE NAME DEBIAN>-backports reinstall <PACKAGE NAME>`
- Example: `sudo aptitude -t buster-backports reinstall jami`

Note

- This option above is for Debian 10 Buster. If you use Ubuntu, you would need to adapt this command. Related documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

#### Option 4: ALL packages. WITH Backport.

- Format: `sudo aptitude -t <CODE NAME DEBIAN>-backports reinstall '~i'`
- Example: `sudo aptitude -t buster-backports reinstall '~i'`

Note

- This option above is for Debian 10 Buster. If you use Ubuntu, you would need to adapt this command. Related documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports
  Note
- This option above will both reinstall ALL already installed packages and reset their permissions to their default. Including your operating system (OS). Before executing this command, it is suggested to complete the appropriate actions. Such as, but not limited to, create a backup, check that you have enough available locale storage. Time needed for this command is similar to installing a new OS.

#### Notes about all four options above

- Depending on the package, most of the time, those commands above will reset the permissions only on the package folder(s) & file(s). Other files, such as configuration file(s) may not be affected. In other words, the configuration file will remains unaffected. If needed, and if appropriate you could manually reset the permissions on the configuration file(s) only. Often those configurations file(s) are stored at a different location. For example, but not limited to, somewhere into the user home folder. If unsure, find each package documentation.

## Attribution

Thanks to this Debian wiki for those options above at https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions/ResetPackagePermissions

Answer (score -1):

I did the same mistake by accident and with these steps my problem was solved.

*I was logged out from root and I couldn't run commands with root permissions, and I was working on **debian 10**.*

1-Start or re-start your computer and press **ESC**(in some machines, press and hold Shift key) to show the Grub boot menu.

2-Choose "**Advanced Options for...**" from menu and boot the kernel entry with(recovery mode)

3-It gives you a root shell if you have your root password, so you can run these commands

chmod -R 755 /bin /boot /dev /etc/ /home /lib /lib64
/media /mnt /opt /run /sbin /srv /usr /var

chmod -R 777 /initrd.img /vmlinuz

chmod -R 1777 /tmp

chmod -R 555 /sys

chmod -R 555 /proc

chmod -R 700 /root

4-If you get an error when you want to log in as root user, you can run **chmod +s /bin/su** and check the result with **ls -lt /bin/su**
the result should be like this -**rwsr**-sr-x instead of -**rwxr**-sr-x

I hope it helps.

Comment: Generally this approach is inadvisable because one cannot be sure one has correctly set all the permissions. Fixing enough stuff to get the system working may not mean that everything is okay. Also, things differ between Ubuntu and Debian. On my system there are no `initrd.img` and `vmlinuz` files in the top level directory, and the real versions of those files should not have 777 permissions which would be a security disaster - on Ubuntu such files are likely to be found in `/boot` and are symlinks - symlinks have dummy permissions of 777, not the permissions of the files they link to.

Answer (score -1):

I did the same thing. In short. I **did not reinstall my system**. When I noticed that it is running not under all files under the current directory I immediately canceled my command. Then I saw **I CANNOT RUN** `sudo`!

Whenever I try to run `sudo` I get below error message.

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable 
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

When I googled I found https://www.thegeekdiary.com/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-world-writable-how-to-correct-the-permissions-of-sudoers-file/

basically, it says to execute `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` as **root**. How can I be root if I can't type `sudo`?

To do that I go into recovery mode in Ubuntu like https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/488768. From there I log in as root then I executed `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` Then I can execute `sudo`. When I execute a command with `sudo` I get another warning saying `sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable` I executed `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d` to fix that.

After that, I see many weird things such as I cannot do SSH on my machine. I deleted the "OpenSSHD" program and then reinstalled it. When I delete and reinstall I see many warnings

```
WARN: /etc/default/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /etc/default is group writable!
WARN: /etc is group writable!
WARN: / is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw/user.rules is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /lib is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/applications.d is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/after6.rules is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw/ufw-init is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/ufw.conf is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw/user6.rules is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/before6.rules is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/after.rules is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/before.rules is group writable!
WARN: /usr/sbin/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /usr/sbin is group writable!
WARN: /usr is group writable!
```

Then I followed the suggestions of [How to fix permissions warnings in the root folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/427870/488768)

Then I still see my server name is changed. So set the name in "/etc/hosts" Then I still cannot SSH to the given name of my server. Then we changed the IP address back to the previous one. I don't know how IP address changed.

Comment: Who wants to DELETE THIS? This answer might save WEEKS of work, reinstalling your OS and system.