# how to reset Ubuntu 12.04 root permissions?

Tags: permissions

I run this command "**sudo chmod -R 777 /**" by mistake.
After restart, the OS became very wired, no internet access, many things doesn't work, can't open any software...

is there any possible way to reset that! or undo this command?!

Comment: You can either reinstall Ubuntu or correct each folder manually (more or less), but with some risk of things still not working correctly. For reinstalling, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/267012/241580) post will help you get a list of packages you have installed. For correcting permissions manually, I have [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/431104/241580) post on fixing /var.

Comment: See also [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/265093/241580) post, which is effectively the same as your issue.