# how to recover the default owner of /usr and it's subfiles

Tags: 15.04, ownership

My user name was `jamin`,and  I used the command

```
sudo chown jamin -R /usr
```

Then something wrong with some of my software and cmd,and I aware of that I was stupid for what I was done just now.

Then I used the command:

```
sudo chown root -R /usr
```

For now, the Software Center can't work and so was others.
I want to recover the default owner of of /usr and it's subfile.

I'm a fresh. Any body Help?

Comment: most of that is owned by root:root, but if chown root:root does not work is is likely faster and more reliable to do a fresh install. Lesson learned, do not change system files without backup and understand what you are doing first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore the default chown permissions on a directory / file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300557/how-to-restore-the-default-chown-permissions-on-a-directory-file)

Comment: Yeah,I draw a lesson from it! I've installed many libs and software in my ubuntu,I do not want to reinstall it.