# cupsd using 100% CPU, creating large (80GB+) error_log

Tags: permissions, printing, log

A few days ago I realized my Ubuntu machine wouldn't load after login. After some digging around on a liveCD I realized my HDD was at 100% capacity, so I deleted some large files and was able to log in. I didn't have sudo permissions any more and had to boot into recovery mode and change the sodoers file, but eventually recovered root permissions.

I then noticed my machine was a little sluggish, and `top` was showing cupsd using 100% CPU. I've never seen this program before but I soon realized it was a legitimate program.

I the deleted about 40GB worth of videos, only to see my drive space deplete almost instantly in front of my eyes. With a little research and intuition, I realized it might be a a log file being blown up, and sure enough `ls -lh /var/log/cups/` shown me an error_log file that was 80GB+ large.

I deleted the file `sudo rm -rf /var/log/cups/error_log`, killed the service with `sudo service cups end`, and went on my business. I realized after that it would have been a good idea to check out the contents of error_log before I deleted it, but I wanted to get rid of the thing before I was locked out again.

That was yesterday. Today, I started my laptop again and saw cupsd running again at 100% cpu, and sure enough I see my disk space depleting. I stopped the service and run `tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log`, and there are millions of lines of this:

```
W [15/Jul/2015:11:23:03 -0700] Notifier for subscription 911 (dbus://) went away, retrying!
E [15/Jul/2015:11:23:03 -0700] File "/usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus" has insecure permissions (0100777/uid=0/gid=0).
```

==EDIT=================================================================

`ls -l /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus` shows permissions and ownership as `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root` when they should be `-rwxr-xr-x 1 daemon root`, as described in the comments. `sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus` also did not fix the ownership problems.

Finally I removed and reinstalled cups, but to no avail. These links were given as potentially helpful guides,([accidentally chmod -R on /](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidently-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc),[restore chown permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300557/how-to-restore-the-default-chown-permissions-on-a-directory-file)) but they ultimately result in suggesting a reinstall of the OS itself.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus`? I had a similar problem a long time ago and the only easy way to solve it was to disable CUPS... (no printing then)

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root 14k Sep 5 2014 /usr/lib/notifier/dbus

Comment: What does cups do anyway? I mean if it can be disabled without serious repercussion ....

Comment: It does most of the stuff for printing, so without it you can't print. I think the permissions on the file should be `-rwxr-xr-x` *(thats what the permissions are on my Ubuntu 14.04 install)*, so you may be able to fix the problem by running `sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus` (and then restarting CUPs or the computer).

Comment: Printing as in printing paper? The permissions are now `-rwxr-xr-x` however after restart cupsd still runs at 95%+ and creating large error_log file (however seemingly not as quickly?).

Comment: Has the contents of the log changed? Printing as in printing paper yes, some PDF printy things may need it as well.

Comment: First, sorry for the intermittent reply, we just cancelled our wifi in the house and I'm on my phone. The log has the same error messages.

Answer (score 17):

For Ubuntu 15.10 what worked for me was:

```
sudo service cups stop
sudo rm /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf*
sudo rm -r /var/cache/cups
sudo service cups start
```

(If you cannot stop cups try):

```
ps aux | grep cups
```

Get process id (pid) from output and:

```
kill -9 (pid you have learned here)
```

Comment: I did this and it helps, but only until I restart my PC. Is there any way to make this last?

Answer (score 3):

## On Debian 9

1. *user@machine:* `sudo su`
2. *root@machine:*

```
chown -R root:root /usr/lib/cups/* && \
chmod -R 755 /usr/lib/cups/* && \
/etc/init.d/cups restart
```

> *return:*
>
> [image: ok Restarting cups via systemctl cups.service]

and save my log and my cpu

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to comment, so this is in the form of an answer:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus
```

might help, now that you have the permissions right. Who is user 1 on your system? If you don't know how the permissions/ownership of the file were changed from the default, the problem might be the tip of an iceberg. If so, reinstalling would be advisable.

Comment: I ran the command and restarted and nothing seemed to change. Not sure how to find out who user 1 is. What do you think could be "the rest of the iceberg" as you put it...?

Comment: User 1 on a newly installed Ubuntu system is daemon. That your ls command returned `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root` as opposed to `-rwxr-xr-x daemon root` suggests corrupted or missing system files. The daemon user, 1, is not associated with a name in /etc/passwd.

Comment: I just looked at /etc/passwd and user 1 was daemon, but I guess your say my problem is not associated with that. How would I find who user 1 is then?

Comment: If user 1 is daemon in passwd, that's what ls should show as the user owning the dbus file. Have you tried re-installing cups? Be sure to back up /etc/cups first.

Comment: Edit: `id daemon` gives me `uid=1(daemon) gid=1(daemon) groups=1(daemon)`

Comment: I can try that but I'll need to find internet first.

Comment: Any local configuration you've done should be preserved in your backup of /etc/cups, so you can restore it from there. After reinstalling, check that the output of `ls -l` for the dbus file is correct: user=root, group=root, permissions as noted previously.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion, also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidently-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc

Comment: And this discussion, http://askubuntu.com/questions/300557/how-to-restore-the-default-chown-permissions-on-a-directory-file which describes symptoms very similar to what you've described, including the runaway error_log messages. The discussion refers to the discussion at the link in my previous comment, and the upshot (downshot?) of both is that reinstalling the entire system is recommended. Good luck.

Comment: I've re-downloaded cups (`sudo apt-get remove cups`, `sudo apt-get install cups`) and this message caught my eye when installing:

WARN: / is world writable! WARN: / is group writable! WARN: /usr/sbin/ufw is world writable! WARN: /usr/sbin/ufw is group writable! WARN: /usr/sbin is world writable! WARN: /usr/sbin is group writable! WARN: /usr is world writable! WARN: /usr is group writable!

Also, `ls -l /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus` still shows root root.

Comment: I am guessing it already is owned by root from the `rwxrwxrwx 1 root 14k Sep 5 2014 /usr/lib/notifier/dbus` `ls-l` output.... @wndg could you edit that info into your question so it is readable, and have you modified the permissions on `/` at any point (and is disabling CUPS a suitable answer)?

Comment: @wndg, Those warnings are about the iceberg I mentioned earlier. If you want to try to fix the permissions/ownership problems, see the links I provided to other discussions for some possible techniques, but probably the least time-consuming solution is re-installing Ubuntu. Be sure to back up any extensive configuration changes you've made along with any personal files, and check permissions and ownership carefully before replacing saved configuration files, etc. in the new installation.

Comment: I think I'm going to reinstall. I've had a stable Ubuntu machine for 2 years now and seemingly something bazaar has happened, either to me or because of me. @Wilf I don't recall ever modifying permissions in that fashion, no. The last thing I can remember, this all started after I hooked up my friend's iPhone to my computer to pull some photos from it. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I had accidentally messed up my permissions and ownership by using chown on /. Had to spend an evening clearing that up but this I saw a few days back. And your solution fixed it straight away. Putting this in a comment if anyone finds themselves in similar situation

Answer (score 1):

simply done it ,It's working for me :

1) `sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/`

2) `ll /usr/lib/cups/notifier/`

3) `sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart`

done it !!!

Comment: Could you please comment what exactly this does, or why it solves the problem?