# /var/log/cups/error_logs eats most of the memory

Tags: networking, printing, error-handling, logs

I have tried most of the suggestion given by google but I am disappointed. Still my `error_log` file keep increasing by unbelievable size.

I have done following exercise:

```
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed
sudo service avahi-daemon stop
avahi-browse -a | grep Printer
sudo cupsctl --no-share-printers
```

Also in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` (making "browsing=off") and 
`/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` (making "browsing protocol=none")

Even I have tried to put it in logrotate:

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/cups

    /var/log/cups/error_log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
             if [ -e /var/run/cups/cupsd.pid ]; then
                      invoke-rc.d --quiet cups force-reload > /dev/null
                      sleep 10
             fi
    endscript
    compress
    notifempty
    create 640 root lpadmin
    }
```

error_log :  E [02/Sep/2016:13:45:31 +0530] File "/usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus" has insecure permissions (0100757/uid=0/gid=0).      [only this error fills up whole memory !]

Nothing is working.

Comment: What causes all these errors? My error log is always nearly empty.

Comment: I don't know exact reason. In general case it should be nearer to empty.

Comment: Which error occurs the most often? Please post it in your question.

Comment: I have added that error logs in question.

Comment: Thank you , but I have checked http://askubuntu.com/q/648807/569952 though I am not satisfied about the answers.

Comment: finally done it . by providing o755 to notifier folder. Thanks for help .