# Error_log file size from Var/Log/Cups/ is increasing so much (70GB+)

Tags: log, error-handling, logs

Error_log file size from Var/Log/Cups/ is increasing so much (70GB+) and wont stop until i get the error saying i don't have enough space left.

```
***Error_log***



W [08/Jun/2017:18:59:48 +0530] Notifier for subscription 3 (dbus://) went away, retrying!

E [08/Jun/2017:18:59:48 +0530] File \"/usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus\" has insecure permissions
```

These 2 errors are written constantly to the Error_Log. I think about 50 Megabytes/sec. Making system lag

Comment: There are a couple of other questions related to this problem, [https://askubuntu.com/questions/819602/var-log-cups-error-logs-eats-most-of-the-memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819602/var-log-cups-error-logs-eats-most-of-the-memory) and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/648807/cupsd-using-100-cpu-creating-large-80gb-error-log](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648807/cupsd-using-100-cpu-creating-large-80gb-error-log)  The second question in particular, points to odd or possibly incorrect file permissions.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -aR /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo service cups stop
sudo rm /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf*
sudo rm -r /var/cache/cups
sudo service cups start
```

Comment: This may assist the OP in keeping the system operational, but does not address his question of *why* CUPS is writing so much data