# cupsd is consuming 100% cpu and creating large (832GB+) logs

Tags: 16.04, process, cups-lpd

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.When I was running ambari-server,cloudera image in docker container and apache hadoop the system was not responding anymore.One fine day I observed that my total hard disk was filled with error log files under the path "/var/cache".

I have deleted all log files and freed my disk.I have checked running process using `top` command,suddenly I was able to find what is the cause for all these problems.`cupsd` is consuming 100% cpu all times.When I stop the cups service by running `service cups stop` command it stops the cups till the system is up and running.If I restart my system cupsd is again running and consuming total cpu.

I have searched in many forms to stop `cups` perminantly and ran following commands

```
echo "manual" > /etc/init/cups.override
servise cups stop
apt-get remove cups
echo manual > /etc/init/cups-browsed.override
systemctl disable cups.socket cups.path cups.service
systemctl kill --signal=SIGKILL cups.service.
```

All these commands are temporarily stopping cups.When I restart the system cups is again consuming total cpu.

I tried to remove all packages of cups by following commands.

```
apt-cache pkgnames cups
```

which lists all cups related packages. Then I removed all packages using

```
apt-get remove <package name>
```

Still `cupsd` is running and consuming total cpu.
Can anybody give a proper solution for this problem?
Also tell me is it to stop `cupsd` or not.

Comment: what it the error in the logs?

Comment: I have deleted all log files as they are in few GB size.I will be back with the errors in the logs soon. Thank you, Mr.ravery.

Comment: I have fixed the issue.If anybody got this problem remove all packages regarding 'cups' and remove all error log files under /var/cache directory.Finally, reboot your system.That's all.

Comment: that's may stop the problem, but it isn't a fix since `cups` is needed for printing. A better solution would be to find out what error is being written to the logs, and fix it.

Comment: Have a look at this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/648807/cupsd-using-100-cpu-creating-large-80gb-error-log