# Something filling my hard disc rapidly

Tags: 13.04, mount

I should have space but really dont have space:
Code:

```
Filesystem         1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6          302247360 302247360         0 100% /
none                       4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                 4005096         4   4005092   1% /dev
tmpfs                 804408      1732    802676   1% /run
none                    5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                 4022040        12   4022028   1% /run/shm
none                  102400         8    102392   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1             507904     51464    456440  11% /boot/efi
/home/abc/.Private 302247360 302247360         0 100% /home/abc
/dev/sdb1          302247360 302247360         0 100% /media
```

Something is filling my hard disc.Today i made a mistake changed the ownership of /usr.Then i could not use startx after this change.So used sudo startx.But the system did not see my external hard disc.I trıed to mount it with mount with
Code:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media
```

When it gives the no space error, i tried to unmount this but it says: "media not mounted". I do not know if all these are related with no space issue but maybe there is relation.So what should i do to stop the hard disc filling action?

Comment: I made a mistake once.I changed the ownership of the /usr directory.So it generate many log error under /var/log directory.There was a 265 G log.So i deleted it and changed the ownership of the /usr directory to root again.It is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your mistake of changing the permissions in /usr, there are no easy way to recover. There are some hints in the answer to this questions though:

[How can I recover from chmod -R a-wrx / command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265080/how-can-i-recover-from-chmod-r-a-wrx-command)

To track down what is eating space, you can use `du':

> Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories.

Start in the file system root and dig your way down.

```
cd
sudo du -d 1 2>/dev/null | sort -nrk 1
```

Arguments:

- -d 1, du will only show next level of directories and their total size
- 2>/dev/null, redirect stderr to /dev/null, basically hide errors
- |, pipe output to program `sort'
- -nrk 1, sort numerical (n), reverse (r), sort on first "column" (k 1)

This will give you output in the line of:

```
$ sudo du -d 1 2>/dev/null | sort -nrk 1
5423982 .
3037236 ./usr
1113212 ./var
640304  ./home
411632  ./lib
93828   ./opt
92402   ./boot
13008   ./etc
11660   ./sbin
9440    ./bin
1076    ./run
```

This tells you that the biggest "space thief" is /usr, go to that directory and repeat your steps to find the biggest thief in that directory.