# "sudo must be owned by uid 0" when installing a package

Tags: apt, permissions, sudo

I installed npm and tried to install a package:

```
npm install -g reaction-cli
```

I got an error like:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
```

So, I tried to add permission with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib
```

But when I try to install other software, for example

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

I get:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin 
"sudoers_policy" sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0 
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Is there any method to resolve my problem?

I also using `sudo chown -R $USER /src/http` to access source in Apache server to edit files. Then I don't get this error.

Comment: There's almost never a reason to `chown` system files. You should use `sudo` to gain elevated privileges when needed

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/a/884657/158442