# Can't open terminal after using chmod

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I have a problem with my Ubuntu, I installed tomcat server and set it up, but I needed to change one directory and grant my current user read permissions over it so I executed:

```
chmod -R 644 /bin
```

And from there on I kept getting errors, like if i tried to change directory I would get output that there is no such command, so I tried to reopen it (terminal), now when I try to open terminal again it automatically closes, can anyone explain why is this happening and is there a way to reverse it ?

Comment: @dessert So reinstall is a must ?

Comment: Well, I'll just reinstall, it was fresh installation anyway, one more thing to note down for future.

Comment: A re-installation is the best and hassle free way to go in this case. it might take you hours to figure out each files permissions and set them back manually, a fresh install costs you less time and is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please don't change permissions in order to read root-owned files**. In future, if you want to read a file you don't have access to, use `sudo cat` or `sudo less` or open a text editor with root permission. If you think you really need to change permissions for some reason, then first do research or ask a question about it. It's all too easy to break your system with `chown` and `chmod`.

Anyway, your user already *had* read permissions on that directory and all its contents. The `/bin` directory has permissions `755` or `rwxr-xr-x`, as do the vast majority of its contents. They can be read and executed by any user.

You removed the execution bits (`644` = `rw-r--r--`), making the files readable for all, writeable for root, and executable for no user.

When you remove the execute bits from a directory, you make it impossible to enter the directory, except for root.

When you remove the execute bits from a file, you make it impossible to execute the file, even for root.

The Bash program is located at `/bin/bash`. You have made the directory it is in inaccessible, and you have made the binary file itself non-executable, so not even root can run it. `chown` and `chmod` are also in `/bin`, so you can't even use another shell to run them, if you happen to have one that isn't in `/bin`.

Reinstalling your system is the best way to be sure you've got everything right, but if you would like to try fixing it or you really want to avoid that, what you could do is boot from a live system (eg USB installation media or System Recovery), mount your root partition, and change the permissions from there. See [terdon's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/884657/527764) for the best method of doing this (replace `/etc` with `/bin` and use `chmod` instead of `chown`).

Comment: To further explain, execute bit on a directory is required to access anything beyond that directory in a path traversal, so for example `/some/path/file1` can't be accessed without execute permission on `/some` and `/some/path`.  You can list the contents of a directory with only read access to it, you just can't access any of those contents.

Comment: I had to enable IDE to read content of those folders, IDE was installed under my user permissions and tomcat was owned by another user specially created for tomcat. I reinstalled and fixed everything. Also that /bin is not Linux /bin directory, but a directory in /opt/tomcat, I just didn't specify absolute path as I already had /opt/tomcat as working directory in my terminal so I had to grant certain read permissions to my user.