# Tutorial: Fix a CHMOD Disaster

Tags: boot, permissions, chmod

I was trying to run `chmod` on some files and accidentally specified the wrong directory. Now, `sudo` doesn't work, and I rebooted. I can log in, but I can't do anything as root. How can I fix this?

This is different than [Set myself as owner of /etc with chown command now getting all kinds of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300641/set-myself-as-owner-of-etc-with-chown-command-now-getting-all-kinds-of-errors)
as this describes what to do if you can't boot your system. It also addresses problems that may be encountered if you ran `chmod` on another directory or just accidentally specified `/`, like I did. It also explains how to fix `sudo` when/if it gets broken.

Comment: It would help if you divide it into a question and an answer. This isn't a forum.

Comment: it would be better to post the fix as an answer to your question then accept it. That way people searching will see that it has an answer.

Comment: Okay, will do that.

Comment: The duplicate itself is closed as a duplicate, which you should also see. You should also see take some time to read terdon's excellent answer before blindly stating your question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix the problem **WITHOUT** reinstalling.

1. ***Find Your Operating System Version***

   **If You CAN Boot Your System And Log In**

   Open up a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `lsb_release -a`. Look at the 'Description' field. Write down what is in this field.

   **If You CANNOT Boot Your System Or Log In**

   Power off your computer if it's not already off. Power it back on, and press and hold the 'Shift' key until you see a full screen menu.

   Use the arrow keys to highlight the `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` option. Press Enter. You will see a list of options. Pick the first one that has `(recovery mode)` at the end of it. Press Enter. Wait until a menu comes up.

   Use the arrow keys to highlight the `root` option. Press Enter twice. Type `lsb_release -a`.

   **Notice:** You may see 2 or 3 lines of text pop up on the screen mentioning something about a dependency. Just press Enter.

   Note the OS version in the description field. You will need this later.

   Press Ctrl+D. The menu with the `root` option will reappear. Select the `resume` option with your arrow keys and press Enter. At this point, power the system off.
2. ***Fix `sudo`***

   Boot into recovery mode and drop to a root prompt. Enter the following commands:

   `mount -o remount /`

   This remounts your boot drive in read-write mode. Without this, the next commands will fail.

   `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`

   `chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/lib/sudo`

   `chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so && chmod 4755 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`

   `chown root:root /etc/sudoers && chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers`

   `chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d && chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers.d`

   `chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/README && chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers.d/README`

   `chown root:root /var/lib/sudo && chmod 4755 /var/lib/sudo`

   Press Ctrl+D. Select the `resume` option with the arrow keys and press Enter. Power the system off.
3. ***Download The OS And Put It On A DVD/Flash Drive***

   Next, download the version of Ubuntu listed in that field. Using another version can result in this process failing. Put the OS on a DVD or a flash drive.
4. ***Boot The Affected Computer Off Of The USB Drive/DVD***

   Insert the disc or plug the flash drive into the `chmod` affected computer. Power the computer up and tell it to boot off of the USB drive or DVD. You may have to consult your computer manufacturer on how to do this. Let the computer boot. This may take a while, depending on the speed of your computer.

   When you see a menu pop up with 2 options, `Try Ubuntu` and `Install Ubuntu`, click the `Try Ubuntu` option. You should see a desktop. Open 2 file explorer windows. One should be at the root of the computer's boot drive, and the other should be at `/home/<your_username>`, on your computer's boot drive.
5. ***Get The Permissions Of The DVD/USB Drive's OS***

   Open up a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T). Type `sudo su`. Next, type the following commands.

   `find /bin -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > bin`

   `find /boot -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > boot`*

   `find /dev -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > dev`

   `find /etc -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > etc`

   `find /lib -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > lib`

   `find /proc -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > proc`

   You may see some errors here. You can safely ignore these.

   `find /run -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > run`

   You may see an error here. You can safely ignore it.

   `find /sbin -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > sbin`

   `find /usr -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > usr`

   `find /var -depth -printf 'chmod %m %p\n' > var`

   *Only if you cannot boot your system.

   Now, close the terminal. Open another file explorer window and navigate to /home/ubuntu. Xubuntu will use /home/xubuntu. Kubuntu will use /home/kubuntu. Follow this naming convention accordingly.

   You will see 9 or 10 files. They are named bin, boot*, dev, etc, lib, proc, run, sbin, usr, and var. Copy these to YOUR home folder.
6. ***Applying The New Permissions***

   **If You CANNOT Boot The System And Log In**

   Open another terminal. Type `sudo su`. Next, type `fdisk -l`. Look for your boot drive or your drive with /home mounted to it. It is usually the largest drive with the largest partition. In my case, it is /dev/sda1. Note this down.

   Next, type `cd /`. After that, type `cd /mount`. Then type `ls`. You should see one and only one directory. Type `cd /<directory>`. Next, type `mkdir mount1`. After that, type `mount -t ext4 <disk here> /mount/<directory>/mount1`, replacing `<disk here>` with the drive name you wrote down.

   Now, type cd `/mount/<directory>/mount1`. You are now in the root directory of the damaged boot drive. Type `cd /home/<username>`, replacing `<username>` with YOUR username. Type `gedit boot`. If it says that gedit is not installed, type `mousepad boot`. If it says that mousepad is not installed, replace mousepad with the name of your distribution's default text editor in ALL LOWERCASE. A window will pop up. Use the text editor's find and replace feature to replace `/boot` with `/mount/<directory>/mount1/boot`. Tell it to replace exact matches. Once you have done that, go to the very top of the file, press Enter at the beginning of the first line, go to the new blank line, and type `#!/bin/sh`. Click File, then Save As, and save it as boot.sh. Close the file and go back to the terminal.

   Type `chmod +x boot.sh`. No messages should pop up. Finally, type `./boot.sh`. You may see some errors, you can safely ignore these.

   Follow the instructions in the next section.

   **If You CAN Boot The System And Log In**

   Reboot the computer. When it says to remove the installation media, do so. Let the computer reboot. You may see copious quantities of errors during the boot process. Ignore these. Open your /home directory and a terminal. Type `sudo su`. Type your password. Type the following commands:

   `chmod 777 bin`

   `chmod 777 dev`

   `chmod 777 etc`

   `chmod 777 lib`

   `chmod 777 proc`

   `chmod 777 run`

   `chmod 777 sbin`

   `chmod 777 usr`

   `chmod 777 var`

   BE CAREFUL when you run these commands. Make sure the terminal prompt says `root@computername:/home/<username>#` when there's nothing typed in.

   Now, type the following commands:

   `./bin`

   `./dev`

   `./etc`

   `./lib`

   `./proc`

   `./run`

   `./sbin`

   `./usr`

   ^

   This is the longest one. In my case, the text file was 10.4 **megabytes** in size.

   `./var`

   When running these commands, you will get **OODLES** of errors. Don't be worried by this. In fact, they may go by too fast for you to read. Wait for a prompt to return before issuing the next command.

   Your system will appear to have been completely trashed after this. Shortcuts will stop working and applications will stop opening. Exit the Terminal, save your work, and close all applications. Force your computer to power off. Power it back on. Let it boot back up and log in. Also, `sudo` will break again.

   Follow the next section to fix `sudo`.
7. ***Fix `sudo` (Again)***

   Boot back into recovery mode and drop to a root prompt. Type the following commands:

   `mount -o remount /`

   This remounts your boot drive in read-write mode. Without this, the next commands will fail.

   `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`

   `chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/lib/sudo`

   `chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so && chmod 4755 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`

   `chown root:root /etc/sudoers && chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers`

   `chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d && chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers.d`

   `chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/README && chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers.d/README`

   `chown root:root /var/lib/sudo && chmod 4755 /var/lib/sudo`

   Press Ctrl+D. Use your arrow keys to highlight the `resume` option. Press Enter. Let your system boot up. Log in and open a Terminal. Type `sudo` and press Enter. You should see a list of arguments, but no errors or a `/etc/sudoers is world writable` message.

***Congratulations,*** **you've fixed your Ubuntu install!**

This should only be done as a **LAST RESORT**. There are probably uncorrected security errors that are affecting system security. Plan on backing up your data and reinstalling the system from scratch. I highly suggest formatting your hard disk. If you have `/home` on a separate drive, back up all of your personal files in there and format that disk, too.

The goal of this is to get your system reasonably secure once again after a CHMOD disaster, allowing you to safely get your files off and prepare for a reinstall.

I hope this helped. :)

Comment: `/proc` and `/run` (and likely `/dev`) are ephemeral (RAM-based) filesystems - AFAIK there is no point trying to "restore" their permissions

Comment: `chmod 777` is dangerous. Do not do this.

Comment: You should post this answer here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc . I can see you put a lot of work into this, but there is an easier more reliable method, IMO, use `apt-get` to **reinstall all packages with proper permissions**, see my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc

Comment: I tried the 'reinstall all packages' thing, but it seemed to fail to fix the problem for me.