# How do I change back /etc folder owner to root:root?

Tags: permissions, sudo, putty

Yesterday I accidentally changed the owner of `/etc` folder group using this command:

```
sudo chown -R pts:apache /etc
```

I did this to upload a file from my end.  Later when I tried to change it back to `root:root` it showed this error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1001, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1001, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1001, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I can't use `sudo` anymore because of this.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Boot a 'live' system, mount & navigate to that directory & fix from there.

Comment: how do i boot a live system?'

Comment: Insert Ubuntu install media into thumb-drive, and boot the device. I would check the media is flawless first, but I don't take risks.  Refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014 (it's just booting your install media & using the Try Ubuntu option).  You haven't provided release details (most require the '*Check disk for defects*' to be manually started, latest does it automatically)

Comment: If there were any files in /etc that weren't owned by root (I don't know if there are or not) you may encounter future difficulties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set myself as owner of /etc with chown command now getting all kinds of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300641/set-myself-as-owner-of-etc-with-chown-command-now-getting-all-kinds-of-errors)

Answer (score 3):

Try this command

```
pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
```

Answer (score 1):

These three methods are working in this case:

- Boot from LiveCD (Ubuntu installation media with **Try Ubuntu without installing** option), mount your root partition in liveCD and change owner of `/etc` folder using it:

  ```
  $ sudo mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/sda1 /mnt
  $ sudo chown -R root:root /mnt/etc
  ```

  Reboot
- Or, if you know root's password:

  ```
  $ su 
  # chown -R root:root /mnt/etc
  ```

  Tested both variants and both are working.
- berkancetin's method also works:

  ```
  $ pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
  $ sudo chown -R root:root /etc
  $ ls -ailh / | grep etc
  1046529 drwxr-xr-x 139 root root  12K кві 22 12:38 etc
  ```

For files and directories that are owned not by root (as Rinzwind mentioned), you could run:

```
sudo chown root:daemon /etc/at.deny
sudo chown -R root:bind /etc/bind
sudo chown -R root:dip /etc/chatscripts
sudo chown -R root:lp /etc/cups
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/*shadow*
sudo chown -R root:landscape /etc/landscape
sudo chown mpd:audio /etc/mpd.conf
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql
sudo chown -R root:dip /etc/ppp
sudo chown -R smmta:smmsp /etc/mail
```

The list of files and directories in `/etc/` owned not by root, you could get from other working ubuntu machine with almost the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Not all files in /etc are `root:root`.

You can use the command provided by Gryu or berkancetin but need to change some files:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root  daemon   144 Oct 21  2013 at.deny
drwxr-sr-x 2 smmta smmsp   4096 Apr  1  2016 mail  
-rw-r----- 1 root  shadow  1110 Aug 10  2018 gshadow 
drwxr-s--- 2 root  dip     4096 Apr 28  2019 chatscripts
-rw-r----- 1 root  shadow  1462 Aug  5  2019 shadow
```

There can be more (as this list is from one of my machines)