# Stuck on boot splash screen after chown -R user /*

Tags: boot, ssh, chown

I ran:

```
chown -R [myuser] /*
```

by mistake and now Ubuntu won't boot. All I see is the loading screen for Ubuntu. I cannot `ssh` into the machine. The Apache server is down, but `ping` works. In root shell (when I booted into recovery) I discovered `sudo` didn't work as well due to incorrect permissions for the `/etc/sudoers` file. I managed to fix that. The machine still doesn't boot though.

How do I revert the changes made by `chown -R [mynonrootuser] /*`? How do I get everything back to its default permissions?

Comment: @Nmath I don't see any comments from you or I :)

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the owner names and owning group names can take many hours. Basically you need another partition (or Live USB with persistence and all the Apps installed) and then clone the permissions from the working installation to the broken one:

- [Set myself as owner of /etc with chown command now getting all kinds of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300641/set-myself-as-owner-of-etc-with-chown-command-now-getting-all-kinds-of-errors)

Although I didn't intentionally do this on my own system, I was developing a script and before fully debugged it peformed `chown` on `/etc` and some other system directories. I used the information in the above accepted answer and wrote my own script to fix the owner name and owning group name for every file.

Most people would simply reinstall the system and all the apps previously installed. However for myself I couldn't remember all the configuring I've done in `/etc` and elsewhere over five years so writing a script seemed the path of least resistance.