# How to recover from running "chown -r ubuntu /"

Tags: server, data-recovery, chown

I ran `chown -r ubuntu /` on my system, and everything is gone.  Is there any way to recover?  This is a server server hosted on OHV.

Comment: @user535733 is this system problem can it be fixed by ovh

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/a/884657/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two scenarios:

- You ran this as a regular user (not `sudo`) and you have locked yourself out of *your* account on the server (plus probably also caused some collateral damage).
- You ran this as root and have made the entire system unbootable.

In either case, the data is likely still there, but you'll need a way to access the system.  Most cloud hosting providers have the ability to boot into a "recovery" or "rescue" mode, and OVH is no exception.  See their [rescue mode](https://docs.ovh.com/us/en/dedicated/hardware-diagnostics/#activate-rescue-mode) documentation here, and search their help for "rescue mode" for other documents.

I don't use OVH, so I'm going to run through the general recovery concept here based on my experience with other hosting providers.  You'll probably need to do something like:

- Boot into rescue mode
- Examine the damage (system files or user files)
- Repair if possible (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/884657/1165986) which @muru linked in the comments), which may return you to a bootable system.
- Regardless, it may be difficult to ensure that you've properly reset all files.  Your best bet will still be to backup, reinstall, and recover.

If you cannot return the existing install to a bootable state ...

- Add storage to your server (this will likely be an additional charge)
- Create a new disk in that storage.
- Boot into rescue mode
- Copy over any critical data from the old disk to the new.
- Reinstall Ubuntu on the old disk.
- Copy the backed-up data back to the newly installed system.
- Delete the new drive
- Drop back to your normal storage tier.

Alternatively:

- Add storage to your server (this will likely be an additional charge) that is equivalent to what you already had.
- Create a new drive in that storage.
- Install Ubuntu on the new disk.
- Set the new disk to be the boot drive for the server.
- Boot into the new Ubuntu.
- Mount the old drive into something like `/mnt/old`
- Copy the critical data from the old drive to the new one.
- Delete the old drive
- Drop back to your normal storage tier.