# /etc/sudoers is world writable in linux ssh

Tags: ssh, sudo, etc

I tried everything but nothing works.

`sudo` is not working because it says:

```
/etc/sudoers is world writable
```

Can't login as the root user even if I typed the command `sudo -i`

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted

su: Authentication failure
```

Before this error happened, I tried to change the permission of the `/etc` folder to allow me to create a new folder inside the `/etc` folder, then after I open the ssh the next day, this error came up.

The following commands are the only ones that I remembered to allow me to create a folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /etc chmod a+w test mkdir /etc/backup
```

I'm new to Linux commands so I just search them and tried it on my ssh then this error happens.

[image: errors in terminal]

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set myself as owner of /etc with chown command now getting all kinds of errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300641/set-myself-as-owner-of-etc-with-chown-command-now-getting-all-kinds-of-errors)

Comment: please provide the exact command used; it is more likely your problem is larger than this: if you chmod'ed the whole of /etc/ you got more problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, if that is the command, you have destroyed your system.

Comment: I think I chmod the whole /etc folder.

These are the commands that I remembered:
sudo chmod -R 777 /etc, chmod a+w test, mkdir /etc/backup

Answer (score 5):

> Before this error happens, I tried to change the permission of the /etc folder to allow me to create a new folder inside the /etc folder

There is NO valid reason to alter `/etc/`. This is a system directory maintained by packages/he package manager. If you need a personal directory put it either in `/home/$USER` or if multi-user server in `/opt/etc` (but even those are icky IMO ;)).

You fix this by rebooting into grub rescue or from a live session and then do

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

so it matches

```
r--r----- 1 root root 1800 feb 20 18:38 /etc/sudoers
```

Mind that this might be a futile attempt: if you did something to the whole of `/etc/` you might have changed more then just sudoers file. Then a reinstall without formatting would be the answer.

Comment: I already tried that command: chmod 440 /etc/sudoers but it says: chmod: changing permissions of 'etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted

Comment: "from grub rescue or a live session" will never give a permissions error.

Comment: What is grub rescue or live session? And how can I access that?

Comment: Live session: use the usbstick or dvd or cd you used to create Ubuntu, pick "try" , mount the partitions and then open the terminal. Yoy will have a # prompt and root. Same for grub rescue: you pick command prompt at the grub screen during boot.This one is more hands-on: you need to know how your system is set up.

Comment: Is it the grub rescue? https://itgala.xyz/how-to-enter-single-user-mode-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Can I have an easy and detailed steps how to access that?

Answer (score 0):

You should reboot your system and start as **single user mode**, drop into root shell, change ownership of **/etc/sudoers**:

After reboot press `shfit` until GRUB menu appears, then press `e` to edit, afther that go to the line that starts with `linux /boot/vmlinuz` and replace the end of the line `ro \ console=ttyS0 console=tty0` with `rw init=/bin/bash`.

Instructions from [itgala](https://itgala.xyz/how-to-enter-single-user-mode-in-ubuntu/) with images.

Now `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` at then end the sudoers file should look like this

```
-r--r-----
```

I recommend you to edit sudoers file with `visudo` and for adding more config to `/etc/sudoers.d/my-sudoers`.

Comment: Hi, is it a grub rescue?

Comment: Yes, from that point you have all control over your system.

Comment: I can't see the linux /boot/vmlinuz, only linux /vmlinuz was there: https://snipboard.io/XMywkF.jpg

Comment: I'm already in a root and entered the chmod 440 /etc/sudoers, then what's next? I tried sudo but still it says /etc/sudoers is world writable. https://snipboard.io/VbUudi.jpg

Comment: Also, after the chmod 440 /etc/sudoers, should I reboot again and change the rw init=/bin/bash back to its original?