# How to fix permissions warnings in the root folder?

Tags: permissions

Yesterday I noticed a warning my terminal window showed when I installed Samba. The warning was:

```
WARN: /etc/default/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /etc/default is group writable!
WARN: /etc is group writable!
WARN: / is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw/user.rules is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /lib is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/applications.d is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/after6.rules is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw/ufw-init is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/ufw.conf is group writable!
WARN: /lib/ufw/user6.rules is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/before6.rules is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/after.rules is group writable!
WARN: /etc/ufw/before.rules is group writable!
WARN: /usr/sbin/ufw is group writable!
WARN: /usr/sbin is group writable!
WARN: /usr is group writable!
```

I don't know how long this problem has been around (although I don't think it has been more than a few weeks at most), since I don't use the terminal very often. And I don't know what caused the shift in permissions.

ls -l / output:

```
total 96
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 28 20:00 bin
drwxrwxr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb 19 21:44 boot
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 22  2013 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4440 Mar  1 11:11 dev
drwxrwxr-x 158 root root 12288 Mar  1 11:12 etc
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar  1 00:42 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Feb 19 21:43 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Jan  3 10:55 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-45-generic
drwxrwxr-x  27 root root  4096 Feb  8 12:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  8 11:58 lib32
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 22 09:08 lib64
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root 16384 Jun 22  2013 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x  14 root root  4096 Mar  1 11:12 media
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 19  2012 mnt
drwxrwxr-x   4 root root  4096 Sep  9 07:29 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 209 root root     0 Mar  1  2014 proc
drwxrwxr-x  16 root root  4096 Feb  8 11:55 root
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root   780 Mar  1 11:12 run
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  1 00:18 sbin
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  5  2012 selinux
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb 28 19:24 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Mar  1  2014 sys
drwxrwxrwt  17 root root  4096 Mar  1 11:15 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  11 root root  4096 Feb 20 21:20 usr
drwxrwxr-x  13 root root  4096 Mar  1 01:02 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Feb 19 21:43 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Jan  3 10:55 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-45-generic
```

My question is, what are normal values for permissions in these folders? Would it solve the problem if I removed the group write permissions through the `chmod` command? And are there any other things I should look out for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it would solve the problem if you remove group write permission through `chmod`.

```
sudo chmod 751 <files or directories>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try this

```
sudo -i
chmod 755 /etc /lib /usr
```

Anyone with the same problem, just replace the directories i.e */etc* or */lib* with the erroneous directories. If say, your affected directory is /svr then do `chmod 755 /svr`

More detail on [755 permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638796/what-is-meaning-of-755-permissions-in-samba-share)

Good luck