# Setting permission for Xampp installation directory. see details

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, chmod, xampp

I know bit about setting permission but i'm little in a mess with it.
I'm new to ubuntu so i get little confused and took much time to solve a little problem.
I have installed xampp with installer which put it in `/opt/lampp` i have set Virtual hosts as well i successfully configured my first vhost after spending couple of hours but when i try to create a new one one i lost my access now whenever i open my host url `opencart.lh` it says access forbidden. i tried to play with chmod but i get lost with it.

Note: i didn't create folder manualy in `opt/lampp/htdocs` i just copy my existing project to it like `opt/lampp/htdocs/opencart`.

It might be a duplicate question but i hope you can answer it as well.

Thanks in advance.

## Edit -1

My Question is i have added new folder to htdocs i have settled it's permission chmod 755 for directories and chmod 644 for files this worked for my on my first project but with 2nd i used the same method but it didn't work for that one.

Comment: Take a look on my answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/638799/150504  to learn w little bit about permissions

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is meaning of 755 permissions in Samba Share](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638796/what-is-meaning-of-755-permissions-in-samba-share)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little more effort I'm able to work with my `htdocs` folder.
First i set my owner of my `htdocs` from `root` to `My User`

after that i set permission of my `htdocs` `755 (drwx-rx--rx-)` for my all directories in `htdocs`

User this code to do that

```
find htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and for files i set `644 (rw-r-r)`

User this code to do that

```
find htdocs -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and it works fine.

Yapeeee.

Hope someone will find this use full.

Comment: I'm glad you figured a way to fix the problem. I got a bit lost after your `..chmod 755 ..` bit, but never mind. I still don'tt exactly understand the problem. However I though does ownership of the fiels/directories matters..? sometimes if user is the owner you might need to change it  to root. Also I think you know that, but when you run `chmod` maybe you need to do it recursively ..? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In general to change file and/or directories permissions you need to use `chmod` command (you already knew that).

There is two way to use `chmod` more information in official [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) page. In the nutshell either use letters e.g

- `r` read (readable)
- `w` write (writeable)
- `x` execute (executable)

OR use numbers

- 4 == r
- 2 == w
- 1 == x

  Here are some example that you should be able to adapt them for your own use.

`chmow 644 *`

- 6 make all files in the current directory readable and writeable for the file owner
- 4 make all files in the current directory only readable for people in the group
- 4 make all files in the current directory only readable for everyone else

I don't know equivalent command using letters but to get the same reuslt you would do something like this

`chmod a+rw *`

- all can read and write

`chmow o-w *`

- others can't write

`chmod g-w *`

- group can't write

*There are many different ways to change files and directories permission. You should really look at the docs*

Comment: Thanks Serine.. But i have idea about it and i mostly use 7-4-2-1 method to set like chmod 644 `filename` but my question is not about chmod exactly. It's about that i have added new folder to htdocs i have settled it's permission `chmod 755` for directories and `chmod 644` for files this worked for my on my first project but with 2nd i used the same method but it didn't work for that one.