# How to create folder in mysql5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to upload video php to mysql. i try to create folder but not success.
below step i apply

1. Edited phpmyadmin's config file

   nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
2. Added the path for both upload and save directories

   cfg['UploadDir'] = '/etc/phpmyadmin/upload';
   cfg['SaveDir'] = '/etc/phpmyadmin/save';

but not save. show error

```
Error writing /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error writing /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php: Permission denied

You are trying to upload /save in /etc/phpmyadmin, while this directory have some permissions that disable user from writing on it, so you have to choose one of many scenarios to solve that:

- Change the dir to some dir in your home
- change permission of that dir using chmod. Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/638799/150504) for more info
- change ownership of that dir

Personally I prefer to choose a directory in home to upload/save in unless you want to use this directory system-wide.