# Minimum size of home partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

What is the minimum capacity of `/home` , is it possible to make more than one logical drive for secondary storage?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the minimum capacity of /home

The minimum capacity is as much as you need!!

For me I could use 1TB for /home while for someone else he needs just some Gbs since he doesn't have much data to store.

What I'm trying to say, this is directly relevant to what you and how you use your system and how much you have data to save.

> is it possible to make more than one logical drive for secondary
>   storage?

You can take answer from my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/644291/150504

Answer (score 1):

As Maythux has stated, it really does depend on your needs, though there are some 'gotcha's' which may mean you need more space than you originally think.

One thing to note is that a lot of programs will install stuff in your `/home` directory which can fill it up more quickly than you expect. VirtualBox creates virtual machines in `/home/user/VirtualBox VMs`, and these often take up a lot of space, I currently have 3 configured on an Ubuntu server install, and the `~/VirtualBox VMs` directory is 67G!