# How to add a second SFTP user with only view permissions

Tags: server, sftp

I want to add a second SFTP user that can only view a couple of folders/files in a home folder. I already added a group `sftp_users` for the normal users but now I am searching for a solution to add a read only user for the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be:

- Set a new group (e.g. sftp_users_ro)
- Give the new sftp user the new group
- set the following permissions to the folder: 775

The user and group which owner the folder will have read/write/execute permission in this folder.

The new sftp user will have read/execute permissions to the folder (without write permission)

See this Q&A for more info
[What is meaning of 755 permissions in Samba Share](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638796/what-is-meaning-of-755-permissions-in-samba-share)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you help me with the exact commands that I need to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACLs (Access control lists). You can grant read access to an user with:

```
  setfacl -m u:lisa:r file
```

However, your sftp server needs to support, so check that out before trying. Also, there're some clients which don't support Linux ACLs (I might be wrong but I think WinSCP still doesn't support ACLs).