# /etc/profile permission denied

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, etc

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS partition and I've recently have had issues logging in.

From the GUI login screen, when I enter my username and password, it takes me right back to the login screen. This is different from when I enter my username and password incorrectly.

So I entered alt+ctrl+F1 to access the terminal and I signed in.
It then reads:

```
-bash: /etc/profile Permission denied
```

From what I've tested, the only commands that I can run from terminal are basic terminal commands like ls and pwd. I tried changing my access to `/etc`:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc
```

I get the errors:

```
sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

If I run it without sudo I get a permission denied. If someone knows how to get around this issue that would be great

Comment: do you have root password?

Comment: Please don't use quote to highlight code samples. Use the code tag instead. Thanks

Comment: @Anu what's the output of `ls -l /etc/profile` and `ls -l /etc/sudoers` ?

Comment: Are you sure you did the command there and not `sudo chmod -R 755...`? In that case it will be more or less impossible to recover... because `/etc` is 755 in my machine, so nothing should have happened. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/recovering-from-chmod-r-777-in-ubuntu (there is a question specific here, but the search box is unable to help me... found: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidently-run-command-chmod)

Comment: @rusty my permissions to etc is `drw-rw----` and I get permission denied when I try to run the two commands you mentioned

Comment: @Rmano I don't think it ever tries to run the command because the errors I get when I try to use `sudo`

Answer (score 3):

#### Setting permission to `/etc`:

Since the permission of your `/etc` directory is `drw-rw----`, you will not be able to drop down to root privilege to set the right permissions. So you'll have to get a Live Ubuntu media with which you can boot and correct the problems.

1. Boot to a live session, open a terminal and mount the target root partition:

   ```
   sudo -i
   mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
   ```

   (replace `sdXY` with that of target device, the device for `/`; assuming you don't have a separate partition for `/etc`.)
2. Make permission changes:

   ```
   chmod 755 /mnt/etc
   ```

   (assuming the permissions for the contents in `/etc` is okay.)

   ```
   reboot
   ```

P.S. I tried to replicate this by running `sudo chmod 644 /etc` and was able to recover with the steps stated above. However, I encountered additional issues with Unity plugins. The following AU Q&A helped to solve some:

- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: My permissions in root for `/etc/profile` is `-rw-r--r--` and for `/etc/sudoers` is `-r--r-----`. However when I log in normally, `drw-rw----` are the permissions I have to `/etc/`

Comment: `drw-rw----` for `/etc` is not right, it should be `drwxr-xr-x` and owned by _root_ user and group.. The execute permission for any directory is important to allow the authorized to access the directory and its contents. So, changing the permission with `sudo chmod 755 /etc` (assuming the permission of its contents are good) should do the job for you. You'd have to use a live Ubuntu media for this..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a root password, you can use `su` to become root and then fix the permissions of the files. They should be as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 665 Feb 20 03:43 /etc/profile
```

and

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 745 Feb 10 20:16 /etc/sudoers
```

After setting the permissions, you should `reboot`.

Comment: When I run su I get an Authentication error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have messed with `/etc/sudoers` or some other sensitive file and  been locked out of `sudo`.

But you can use `pkexec` command to fix it.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for more deatil about file permission and `/etc/sudoers`.