# sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory, sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Tags: command-line, nvidia, permissions, sudo

This is the error message I get any time I run `sudo`:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Right now I'm trying to boot ubuntu 14.04 on jetson tx1 (nvidia's most recent development board) using an SD card. I am able to boot Ubuntu without the GUI. However the `sudo` command is seriously broken.

When creating the filesystem on my sd card, I used `sudo` to do it. I found lots of other posts about it and verified that

1. Both user and group have permission to execute `/etc/` ([sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory - File Exists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496632/sudo-unable-to-stat-etc-sudoers-no-such-file-or-directory-file-exists))
2. Using `pkexec visudo /etc/sudoers` gives me this error:

   ```
   ** (process:1784): WARNING **:
   Error enumerating actions:  GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
   Error checking for authorization org.freedesktop.policykit.exec: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
   ```

   ([How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi))
3. The GRUB menu is not accessible because I don't have the GUI. Holding shift down didn't do the trick...

Comment: @bc2946088 sorry just fixed that. I could not copy and paste because it was on jetson tx1

Comment: Ahh, I'm not sure if you can actually change the path anyway.

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` produce?

Comment: @OluDouglas i get `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 11178 Apr 1 2015 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: What does ls -l /etc/sudoers and cat /etc/sudoers produce?

Comment: Assuming you have an internet connection, try `apt-get --reinstall install sudo`

Comment: also make sure your `/etc/` folder is accessible `chmod g+x /etc`

Comment: @OluDouglas  Unfortunately i don't have internet access. I need sudo command to enable wifi from the terminal. /etc/ folder's is executable by both owner and group - this is what i get for /etc/ `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: @CollDue96 `ls -l /etc/sudoers` i get `-r--r----- 1 root root 745 Apr 1 2015 /etc/sudoers`  and for `cat /etc/sudoers` i get `cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied`

Comment: ok, then run `pkexec visudo` and let me know if it's succesful. Also check out this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi)

Comment: @OluDouglas I already tried that and got warnings shown above

Comment: Could you try sudo cat /etc/sudoers?

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix this, you can either reinstall `sudo`, or download a default `/etc/sudoers` and edit it. Both ways require these steps: First, restart your computer. When the Grub screen displays, instead of choosing `Ubuntu xxx`, choose `Advanced options for Ubuntu xxx`. Under `Advanced Options`, choose `Recovery mode`. The second step is to mount your partitions `rw`. To do this, choose `Clean packages`, `Ok`, and then when you see the recovery screen again, select `Root shell`. Enable the wifi from the root shell. Either reinstall `sudo`:

```
apt-get install --reinstall sudo
```

or insert this into `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset

# Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to not need a password
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
# %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

(from [Sudoers Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers))

Before restarting, `su` back to your normal user, and try `sudo apt-get upgrade` or anything with `sudo`. If it works, then reboot. Otherwise, comment with the error message.

Comment: That wiki page is old. Current Ubuntu practice is to use the sudo group rather than admin by default. You should uncomment the sudo group .  (In the default install the admin group line is uncommented for backwards compat for people who have never reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can access the internet on another machine because you posted this question. You can create an Ubuntu live CD, boot into it, and fix `sudo` with the following steps. Mount the partitions of your installation to recreate the filesystem at `/mnt` (`sudo mount /dev/<whatever> /mnt`, `mkdir -p /mnt/home && sudo mount /dev/<whatever2> /mnt/home`...). Insert the default sudoers file from the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) into `/mnt/etc/sudoers`. Reboot into your system and `sudo` should work.