# chown recursively changed permissions

Tags: chown

I ran the chown command in a directory:

`chown -R user:user {.,}*`

The `{.,}*` is used with `mv` and `cp` to include both hidden and listed files. Now this command went through and changed those two files in my directory, but I had to break it to stop since it went on. Now I'm afraid it has gone and changed the permissions on other files and folders, since it didn't terminate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Answer (score 52):

By using `{.,}*`, you included both `./` and `../`. Along with the `-R` option, your `chown` call was about to browse your entire filesystem (and others, possibly mounted), going through `../`. With other commands, this little mistake can be quite deadly, but believe me, you're not the first, and you won't be the last...

Since this operation is quite heavy, your `chown` call hanged a while, as it had a lot of files to process. I'd suggest you go back to the directory where you made the call, and go back progressively to `/` to see what changes were made. You might be able to apply a quick fix doing:

```
chown root:root /* # Set ownership to root for all directories in /.
chown you:yourgroup /home/you -R # Take your home back.
```

On Ubuntu, the `/home` directory is given to the first (admin/sudo) user registered on the system. If you're the only user, you might want to do:

```
chown you:yourgroup /home -R
```

However, a simple `chmod 755` on `/home` is enough, even if it belongs to root.

Having a quick look directly at `/` (including the root permissions themselves, `ls -ld /`) would also be a nice place to start. I suggest you make sure that `/` belongs to root, with a 755 permissions set.

If you used `chown` to set a very specific ownership (a user other than you or root, a rare group, ...), you may want to use `find` to look for `chown`-ed files.

```
find / -user {username}
find / -group {groupname}
```

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `undo` for what your did. Linux doesn't naturally keep tracks of these "casual" operations.

For more information on what you were trying to achieve, have a look at [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/345719/how-to-chmod-and-chown-hidden-files-in-linux).

Comment: My root directory seems to be good. It's owned by root.

Comment: You must have killed `chown` on time then, but keep checking, going from the directory you executed `chown` in, to the root.

Comment: Was the problem here that I used the -R flag? And how can you change owner in one command for both hidden and listed files.

Comment: See the link I added at the end of my answer. The `-R` was the problem, since you went recursively through `..` as well, which eventually led you to altering the entire file tree from `/deep/directory/where/you/chowned` to `/`.