# How to Recover Ubuntu default file system permissions

Tags: permissions, read-only, recovery-mode

I made a big mistake..  When I trying to give some permissions to localhost project

In terminal I typed

```
'sudo chmod -R 755 /'
```

Now nothing work.
I tried to fix this By this commands

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Now I Can't access to GUI

Comment: OK.. It's duplicated, but No solutions in the another Question.

Comment: Yes there is a solution (and it's the only one): http://askubuntu.com/a/43622/344926