# Permission Issue in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permissions

Accidentally in terminal I executed `sudo chmod R 766 /`. Now I am not able to open Ubuntu.How can i resolve this?Is there a way to access terminal? I have dual boot so can I do something from Windows?

Comment: The easiest way is to re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Answer (score 0):

That's why you should use `sudo` very carefully.

Your data are not lost, you can copy them from your existing partition to a USB key with a live CD, but you will have to reinstall your system.

Comment: Will I able to recover the applications?

Comment: The configuration of user applications are in the home folder, so you copy it somewhere and put it back in the new home folder after reinstall, but you will have to reinstall the applications.