# Ubuntu server boots to Console but nothing more

Tags: server, gnome, console

My Ubuntu server just boots to the console and then I can't log in or do anything. It just gets stuck in a boot loop, I have Gnome installed as a GUI.

This happened after I used the command `sudo chmod 766 /` to try to unlock all folders. I did **NOT** use any command involving `-R`.

What shall I do?

Comment: Did you install a GUI? Ubuntu Server by default only comes with a console.

Comment: As I said i have Ubuntu Gnome installed as a GUI, but i won't boot into it after that stupid command

Comment: Oh no. You used `chmod` on the *root directory*! Yes, the system is pretty much gone. But, no - it wasn't  `chmod -R`, was it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Comment: I used `sudo chmod 766 / ` not with any -R ( i don't even know what that is xD)

Comment: Probably the immediate login issue is that `/tmp` needs to be writeable/sticky (octal mode 1777) for X to start

Comment: and how do i do that xD, when i try to use any Sudo command i have to type in my login and password but i can't it just give me the login message again =/

Comment: What about booting from live USB and fixing the permissions from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-R flag is recursive which means it will affect parent directory and all sub directories and files. You have 3 options here really.

1.) just reinstall your system which is nice if you dont want to spend all day figuring out this problem and you didn't have anything you really needed on the system.

2.) extract data then reinstall. if you did have something on there that you needed try booting to a different medium (USB or optical disk) and extracting your file that way then reinstalling.

3.) spend hours trying to figure this problem out before giving up and drinking a 6 pack and playing some video games. then reinstall your system when you're done rethinking your life.

4.) (maybe) get realllllly lucky that someone did that and managed to fix it and that they're not drunk or playing video games so they post the answer in this thread.

Good luck homie

Comment: so i should do this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: The same way you installed Ubuntu in the first place. Boot to the Ubuntu install medium. Look at the Ubuntu install documents they are quite detailed. EDIT: didn't see your link. Yes that exactly.

Comment: Okay I have tried to do as shown in the tutorial but doesn't work.

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu but don't keep any directories that tutorial keeps your home directories which you locked yourself out of. Just do a fresh install just like you did to install Ubuntu in the first place