# Woops. I did "chmod 777 /"

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I was in a rush and accidently did "sudo chmod -R 777/". As you can imagine, everything is broken. I can't access sudo either. Is there a solution to this, or will I have to do a clean install?

Comment: Only `chmod 777 /` wouldn't break anything. Did you do `chmod -R 777 /`?

Comment: Correct. Edited.

Comment: I think I can fix this, but need to test it in a virtual machine, but need sleep first....

Comment: Yeah, I think I might be able to reverse everything, yaay...

Comment: DONE: http://askubuntu.com/a/770998/36315 Not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a new clean install, sorry.