# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi on broadcom starting not wok

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I turned on my Lenovo G510 and the WiFi wasn't working. I does not do anything after yesterday. I tried restarting the network, tried running `rfkill unblock all`, and I tried reinstalling the driver by following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) instructions, but nothing is working.

Here is my generated WiFi-information file:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Jul 2016 21:15 EEST +0300

Booted last: 20 Jul 2016 21:11 EEST +0300

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-65-generic #73~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 21:05:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              532480  0 

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:88.118.218.255  Bcast:88.118.223.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1596894 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:701771 (701.7 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         88.118.223.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
88.118.208.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       831     1  0 21:11 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Auto Ethernet] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         88.118.218.255
    Prefix:          20 (255.255.240.0)
    Gateway:         88.118.223.254

    DNS:             212.59.8.8
    DNS:             212.59.8.4

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Komerservis]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Komerservis | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Komerservis | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Teo-5EC56F-Greitasis]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Teo-5EC56F-Greitasis | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Teo-5EC56F-Greitasis | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Thomson5D3064]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Thomson5D3064 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Thomson5D3064 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Vilnius (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-65-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     381EA511B7BC282E4E24C0E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        9B:61:23:81:C2:74:1F:1D:FD:FE:7D:9E:98:8A:BE:98:59:16:70:2A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist ideapad-laptop
blacklist ideapad-laptop
blacklist ideapad-laptop exit

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a0 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    6.599529] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.600577] alx 0000:09:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[    6.601393] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: What is the result of this terminal command? `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: I do not understand anything now, when I reinstalling broadcom kernel drivers I have to disable Secured boot in bios and then my wifi started working, but why?  I do not enable this thing in a past and wifi was working what changed?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/799863/why-does-chmod-777-r-leave-the-system-unusable/799866#799866

Comment: New kernels use Secure Boot.