# Running "chmod -R 777 / " broke sudo; results in "/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, raspberrypi

I made a big mistake by running:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /
```

After that, a problem appeared, which is that `sudo` won't work anymore.
When I run `sudo` in any command this error appears:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

And when I searched for the problem I figured out that some permissions are messed up
in the `/usr/bin/sudo` file but I can no longer become root so I can change the permissions!

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/799863/why-does-chmod-777-r-leave-the-system-unusable

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc

Comment: -1 Because 30 seconds of Googling would have found you at least one of the above.

Comment: For next time, double check what you type when you prefix with `sudo`.

Comment: I'm afraid reinstalling is the easiest way to go.

Comment: @AndroidDev its ok man 72 hours of work is gone... its ok wat to do we all learn from our mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like re-installing Ubuntu is the easiest way to go from here.

---

### What happened?

Let's look at the command, bit by bit:

```
sudo - executes with root permissions (allows for maximum destruction)
chmod - changes the permissions of files (harmless if used correctly)
-R - recursive, descend into directories (could cause trouble)
/ - when combined with -R and sudo, recursively change all the files on your system to global-read-write-execute (very bad)
```

As you can see, you've basically soft-bricked your system.
Many programs and files on your Linux system require permissions to keep them afloat.

### How can I fix this?

Unless you're willing to spend a lot of your time manually fixing the permissions, re-installing Ubuntu is the way to go.

Backup your data with a live CD, then delete your Linux partitions.

When you install Ubuntu for the second time, create new partitions.

Comment: thanks man im now 100% sure that i screwed up my system but how to backup my files and package?

Comment: @KarrarHyderAl-mosawi Mount the partitions you would like to backup to, copy the files over, then unmount.