# can't boot the system after fsck, libgtk problem

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I tried to do a `chmod` and delete my Pycharm logs. And somehow got in a situation that I can't boot my system.

```
[FAILED]Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories
[FAILED]Failed to start Enable support for additional executable binary        formats

[49.493137] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
[45.515265] acpi_call: Cannot get handle: Error: AE_NOT_FOUND
```

Opening tty1 with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. After entering credentials I get:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd:39
 /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-    
upgrader/release-upgrade-available Directory nonexistent 
usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create usr/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Directory nonexistent
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot No such file or directiory
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1
```

The original problem is still not solved, the same things are present, can’t boot the system. But now after reboot, there is no more error  `[FAILED]Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories`, only the second one. I did many things, but I believe that this answer made difference in the first step https://askubuntu.com/a/748350/741547.

After `sudo apt -f install` I get:

```
Additional packages will be installed libgtk-3-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches to /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 by libgtk-3-bin'

dpkg-divert: error: rename involvs overwriting 'usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 with different file '/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors wew encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb
E. Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After that, thing I tried to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-bin=3.18.6
E: Version '3.18.6-1ubuntu1' for 'libgtk-3-bin' was not found
```

Then I tried to overwrite with `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb`
with same error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors wew encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb
```

After that in tty1 I type `systemctl status binfmt-support.service` and 
I get:

```
Active: failed (Result:exit code)
Process: 1310 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/update-binfmts --enable (code=exited, status=2)
systemd[1]: Failed to start Enable support for additional executable binary formats
```

EDIT2:

Now im in the system with Ubuntu USB and have access to all packages. Can i somehow use ubuntu software center for repairing packages ?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! On what resources did you run `chmod`? I’m afraid it was something like in this case: [Why does chmod 777 -R / leave the system unusable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799863/why-does-chmod-777-r-leave-the-system-unusable) Backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: next problem is, after every install : adwaita-icon-theme : Depends: libgtk-3-bin but it is not oging to be installed. And i cant install anything

Comment: Could you tell us how you solved the original problem? And please don’t add another, unrelated problem to the existing question. You can ask a new question but check [existing questions dealing with the same error](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=but+it+is+not+going+to+be+installed) first.

Comment: Original problem is not solved, still the same things are present, cant boot system. But now, after reboot there is no more error  [FAILED]Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories , only the second one. I did many things, but i belive thst this answer made difference in the first step https://askubuntu.com/a/748350/741547 .

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in comments and add any useful information you can (examples: What was the exact `chmod` command? Why and how have you run `fsck`?). It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)

Comment: Thank you, i did wrote a problem as far as i remeber, this is something i tried over and over, i just forgot a lot of steps.