# Chmod 754 / -R wrongly used on 16.04

Tags: chmod, tmp

I accidentally run chmod 754 / -R in tmp folder and all files and directories in the system have changed binary files and are now inaccessible. After that it didn't allow any single click over an icon, desktop or even a folder.
Now the system is not booting...

Comment: Related to / near-duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option, quite honestly and most likely, will be reinstalling the system.
If you had some important data on the disk, just maybe boot the system from LiveCD, make a copy of your stuff, and then rebuild the system.

Comment: Unless, of course, you want to work out which files had what permissions originally. LiveCD will still be useful :)