# "cd `" (backtick) command results in ">", why and how do I exit it?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I type

```
cd `
```

into a terminal, then I get this

```
>
```

Even `ls` or `cd` is not working. Attempting to run such a command on the `>` prompt just gives another `>` prompt.

Please explain the meaning of the above command. And how do I exit it?

Comment: Ctrl+C or another `. All quotes must be terminated properly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution

Comment: As for the meaning, the single backquote, ` , tells the shell that you are starting a _command substitution_ and `>` means that the shell wants you to complete it.

Comment: Duplicate on Unix & Linux: [What is the effect of a lone backtick at the end of a command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232912/117037), related: [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/q/890782/301745), [Terminal shows > after entering backslash](https://askubuntu.com/q/1107966/301745)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Backticks work in pairs. Bash is waiting for you to provide another backtick to complete the command/expression.

`>` is simply a prompt for newline which is determined by the value of `PS2` generally defined in .bashrc.

Whenever you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (if the command/expression is incomplete, i.e. backtick isn't closed), bash expects you to complete the command/expression either in one line or multiple lines. For example, you want to evaluate value of 'a' using `expr`. You can do

```
$ a=`
> expr 1 + 3`
```

will be interpreted as

```
$ a=`expr 1 + 3`
```

So, if you want to run some command either complete the required expression or if there is no command/expression required in between backticks, refrain from using that. Another way is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but that would be a [Keyboard Interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_interrupt) and will make your command to terminate immediately.

To read more about backticks, read these questions on U&L: [Understanding backtick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48392/322920) and [What does ` (backquote/backtick) mean in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27428/322920)

Comment: This is a good answer but ```a=`echo $b` ``` is in most cases a bad example. You will get the value of `$b`, with all sequences of whitespace replaced with single spaces, then each word will be expanded as a glob based on the files of the current directory, and then all trailing newlines will be trimmed, and a single newline will be added in the end. I'd say that 99.9% of the time you'd want `a=$b`, and the rest `a=$(echo "$b")` if you want a single trailing newline.

Comment: Hey @user000001, thank you for your valuable comment. What about ````a=`expr 1 + 3` ```` example? (Formatting in comments sucks!!!)

Comment: Yes, that's much better, though surely someone will come along and complain that since the question is tagged [bash], you'd be using `a=$((b+3))` in real code instead of `expr` ;)

Comment: @user000001 Replaced. The question is about ``` ` ``` and `>`, I don't think such complain would occur ;-).

Comment: Consider the complaint made -- we've got so many people using 1970s-era `expr` syntax because they're used to seeing it around so they think it's normal/expected/correct, vs standardized-since-the-1990s (and thus not at all a bashism) `$(( ... ))` POSIX math syntax. `date` is a lot more defensible as an example, since it's legitimately needed when writing code for POSIX shells (or versions of bash that aren't recent 4.x adding `printf '%(...)T'`) today.

Answer (score 7):

The backticks create an execution environment called command substitution. It is used like this, for example:

```
echo "The date today is `date`"
```

Here, the `date` command is executed first, and its output replaces the part between the backticks, so in the end you get a string with the current date.

Command substitution may span multiple lines, so when you type:

```
cd `
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, bash expects you to complete the command substitution, before executing the `cd` command. This can be broken either by closing the backtick and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (This will abort the command without anything getting executed).

Note that modern guidelines prefer to avoid the backtick syntax for command substitution, and to use `$(  )` instead, so the first example would be:

```
echo "The date today is $(date)"
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` is a request for more input.

In this case the name of a command is expected to be input. This is because you pressed <kbd>`</kbd> which tells shell that a command name is [about to follow](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

The easiest way out of this accident is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.