# What are the consequences of running chmod 755 -R on home directory?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I accidentally executed

```
chmod 755 -R $HOME
```

For now everything works fine, but I haven't rebooted my laptop yet.

I wanted to know what are the consequences of my actions? I'm especially concerned about configuration files. Could something break?

The only important thing I can think of is to set back correct permissions on **ssh keys**. Is there anything else I should take care of?

I'm aware of exising question: [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc), but it seems to address bigger issue which is running chmod on system directories.

Comment: ssh keys and gpg will not work with those permissions.  As you are the owner of most everything in $HOME you should otherwise be fine.

Comment: Ahh bummer, I've been using \*nix flavors for about 18 years now, and I pulled my first "rm -fr /*" accidentally a couple months ago when my keyboard stuck and the dot key didn't work.  I meant to do ./* .  Fortunately the gods were shining upon me and I also forgot "sudo", but it was still a mess for my home dir...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed the permissions of all files and directories in and underneath `$HOME` from whatever they were (and each file or directory had it own permissions) to `rwxr-xr-x`. This marks all files "executable" , and grants Other (User, Group, Other) users the ability to inspect and traverse the directories and read all your files. The change will break `ssh`, and could cause other problems.

You can fix `ssh` via:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/* ~/.Xauthority
```

I included `~/.Xauthority` to avoid X authentication problems.

Don't execute commands you hear of (read in a book, see online, ...) without understanding what they do. At the very least (for this case) read `man chmod`, `info coreutils 'chmod invocation'` and maybe `man 2 chmod`.

Linux, like Unix, makes it possible to do Powerful Things, but does not require Powerful Things to be Safe. Figure out what it does BEFORE lighting fuse.