# Errors when trying to use `sudo` in WSL (bash on Ubuntu on Windows) after installing jasper

Tags: sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting this message when I try to use `sudo`:

```
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, 0): Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/jp2nyy/pid2: Operation not supported
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, 0): Operation not permitted
sudo: setuid(0): Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to set supplementary group IDs: Operation not permitted
```

This problem started after I installed `jasper` with:

```
sudo apt-get install jasper
```

I'm using Ubuntu Bash for Windows.

#### Edit

As per comments below `chown/chmod` may have been run on files in `/usr` or `/var`.

Comment: What were doing before this issue start?

Comment: The only google hits I can find for this error message relate to ldap and/or pam configuration - have you made changes to either?

Comment: I am unsure if I changed anything for ldap or pam.

Comment: This looks like you did `chown`/`chmod` on files in `/usr` or `/var`

Comment: How does one fix that @muru

Comment: @user3550783 if that's what you did, simplest way is reinstalling: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or other Ubuntu derivative?

Comment: It is the Ubuntu Bash for WIndows @Anwar

Comment: @user3550783 Please remember to include such information next time.

Comment: If you did `chown` or `chmod` something I suggest you check your history (do `history | grep -E 'chown|chmod'`) as depending on exactly what you did it may be fixable...

Comment: Kind of tricky Microsoft getting us to support their product by putting the word "Ubuntu" in front instead of something generic like "Linux Bash" ;)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Canonical developed WSL in partnership with M$

Comment: @Zanna Fair enough.... now that you mention it I vaguely recall reading that a month or two ago.

Comment: @Zanna I tried the history | grep method but it doesn't seem to show the jasper history from yesterday.

Comment: Hmmm sorry I don't know anything about WSL so this is difficult... you didn't get any output grepping for `chown` and `chmod`? Maybe you didn't run those commands. Are you saying the problem started AFTER you installed jasper? I thought you meant you were getting an error trying to install (using `sudo`)

Comment: It srarted after jasper and now I can't use sudo.

Comment: If this is WSL, then you start as root. Why use `sudo` at all?

Comment: I was using sudo as it would say permission denied for some features.

Answer (score 0):

When I had errors (possibly similar to yours) using `sudo` in Ubuntu Bash on Windows, I found that using `sudo -S` seemed to work.