# accidently ran chown on /

Tags: permissions, ssh, root

I was trying to change ownership of a hard-drive mounted on /media/user/ using command

```
sudo chwon -R user:user /media/user/
```

but I made a typo and ran command

```
sudo chwon -R user:user / /media/user/
```

Now everything in `/` is set to user(username) user(group). This system is used by me and my collegue and we cannot ssh into it since permissions have been changed. How do I revert it back to normal ?

Comment: Are you currently logged-in to the system, or can login to the system?

Comment: yes, I am still logged in. But my collegue cannot, even I cannot log-in through new ssh. But the existing ssh session is still active.

Comment: @PoisonAlien - since you are logged in, you can change the ownership of some folder to root (e.g. `sudo chown -R root:root /etc` and other folders`, to allow SSH login to the system, you'll be able to use it for creating backup of the important staff, and follow by re-installing the system

Comment: I cant use sudo. It says 
`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and easiest way would take a live CD and reinstall Ubuntu. By selecting upgrade to Ubuntu, you can reinstall while keeping your files. Most applications and setting should remain.

Reference:
[What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc/43622#43622)

Comment: Thanks, guess this is the best options. Naive question, will it remove other files also ? (as in formatting) and will it also remove all installed softwares ? (so much pain, wish I could go back in time)

Comment: It will reinstall **most** programs. Most settings and themes will be removed, so programs will have to be set up again.

Comment: Oop, forgot to mention, all your files will be kept

Comment: Turns out you cannot upgrade from live CD or USB. I googled a lot, and this is the case. You can only upgrade from terminal. Using  CD you can remove existing and install fresh copy, or install alongside existing OS. I had to do the first one and since I had was only on one partition, I lost all my files :|

Comment: I upgraded a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.04 losing nothing, and in testing did 17.04 to 17.04 and lost nothing, so not sure what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

For login, you may ssh in using root (if the sshd_config allows root login, otherwise you may need a terminal so to login locally) or the `user` (this is to match the permission but with a `chown /` I'm not sure it will work).

You could restore the ownership one by one, for example, `/home/user2` belongs to `user2`, and `/var/www` to `www-data` (takes a very long time). Besides that, the only method would be restoring from backup.