# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: permissions, sudo

By mistake  I entered the command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 somefolder ./
```

Now I am unable to log in to my system as root user. I have the login loop problem

Comment: Why would you want to log in as root? What directory were you in when you ran the command? If you have the error in your title, I guess you must have run it at least on `/usr` if not on `/`. Fixing *recursive* `chmod` is a pain... If you want the least hassle, get your data off there with a live USB and reinstall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Answer (score 2):

Hi i had a similar problem and this is how i solved it.

- First reboot your machine and enter the recovery mode from your grub menu
- Choose the drop to root shell option.This will prompt you with a control-D to continue just press enter
- You are now in a root shell.Do the following

  mount -o  remount,rw  /
   chown  root:root  /usr/bin/sudo
   chmod  4755  /usr/bin/sudo
   exit
- Go back to the menu and choose resume normal boot