# Accidentally did sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/ on Ubuntu Server AWS

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, sudo, aws

I am using AWS to run Ubuntu server 14.04 and by mistake I issued this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/
```

Since issuing this command, I can't switch from ubuntu to root. When I issue this command

```
sudo su
```

It shows me error

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

I don't have a backup of my server.

Comment: No backup? And you "accidentlally" typed `sudo` **ANYTHING***? You broke your system. Start over.

Comment: I didn't get you, now what should I do?

Comment: You can attempt to restore permission see https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc . There are several scripts there, but I posted a method using apt-get from recovery mode as well , take your pick.

Comment: "I don't have a backup of my server." Sorry? @Panther AWS. He wont be able to use a live session. And all other solutions depend on "sudo" working. waltinator is probably correct: delete the instance and recreating it will probably be the only way.

Comment: I don't see how you can resolve this without physical access to the server which you aren't going to get with AWS. Backups aren't optional, they are mandatory.