# How do I recover my remote system from this mistake: sudo chown -R user:group /etc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, putty

Using putty, by mistake, I've used this command to change the folder permission `/etc`:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /etc
```

Now when I'm trying to restart my Apache server the result is:

```
$ sudo service httpd restart

sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 500, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 500, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

**How to recover of this situation?** I don't have physical access, but I have WinSCP and I can change permission directly.

Comment: **Why** you have changed the ownership of `/etc` **!**?

Comment: by mistake i chage after set default set

Comment: It is interesting - is it possible to recover from this mistake while you don't have physical access to the system.

Comment: Please rewrite the question in this way.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the computer?

Comment: i have winscp i can change permission directy

Comment: @JDTheRealHero Isn't there a 'serial console' option in the VPS control panel?

Comment: See the answer I posted in https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc (last answer) . NOTE - It would be nice if my answer were upvoted so that when referencing the Q/A the first thing people see is a working solution rather than "you cant fix this, you have to reinstall" , which is not the case.