# How do I remove the requirement of being root for modifying a certain directory?

Tags: restricted-access

If I execute `ls -al`, i get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root    4096 Jan 16 02:15  <dir-name>
```

But I want:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 <user> <user>  4096 Jan 16 02:15  <dir-name>
```

Comment: You haven’t specified the directory in your question, so I must warn you: Don’t change the owner of system directories! Details: [What if I accidentally run command “chmod -R” on system directories (/, /etc, …)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo chown myuser:mygroup mydir

chown [-c|--changes] [-v|--verbose] [-f|--silent|--quiet] [--dereference]
      [-h|--no-dereference] [--preserve-root]
      [--from=currentowner:currentgroup] [--no-preserve-root]
      [-R|--recursive] [--preserve-root] [-H] [-L] [-P]
      {new-owner|--reference=ref-file} file ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `chmod` a file/folder `sudo chmod 777 <folder>` will allow read/write/execute bits **for anyone** on the system. This however can be a **security issue**. Read [here](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) to find out more.