# php socket flow error 10054. when trying to connect with ssh

Tags: server, ssh, php

I'm using a Bitvise SSH to connect with the server of digital ocean it was working good till yesterday but accidentally I fire the command "sudo chmod -R 0777 /" after that I am not able to connect using SSH. when I am trying to connect get the error as below.

> Reason:FlowSocketReader: Error receiving bytes. Windows error 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't if there's a way to actually "redo" the appropiate permissions for your system, but you can access your machine from [digitalocean's console](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/console/)

Comment: Bring up a new droplet and copy over your configuration and data. It's not worth trying to fix.

Comment: @vidarlo currently we moved(choosed) with this option, However I want to know if any other solution is available or not because some time we have huge db and it will take long time to create new droplet

Comment: @SachinSarola Theoretically you can bring up a new instance, and copy over permissions from this. [That's covered in an answer in the duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/43636). Please read the question linked, and all answers. It's more or less a 100% duplicate.

Comment: @vidarlo thank, next time I will take care of this. My app is working fine but the only issue is not able to connect with ssh and your given link has not content related to this topic :)

Comment: You can't, you will have to access a local console, or perhaps even boot with a live session to restore permissions.