I got an error and read the problem was the permissions at root
I got an error and read the problem was the permissions at root.
I entered
sudo chmod 700 /

Every icon on my screen disappeared and the machine won't boot
How can I get back into my machine? Ubuntu 22.04

Reinstall. You killed the OS

If it was not executed recursively, then look at this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1154502/1157519

If it was however recursive, then this: https://askubuntu.com/q/43621/1157519

I actually figured out to try that before you mentioned it. But running chmod 755 / from root prompt in recovery mode doesn't seem to have changed the permissions.

It wasn't recursive. I guess I'll just reinstall the OS. That's messed up that Ubuntu doesn't give you a warning this simple command will kill your OS.

"running chmod 755 / from root prompt in recovery mode doesn't seem to have changed the permissions" ... it should work provided you re-mounted the system partition in read-write mode (mount -o remount,rw /) first

Nevermind, I tried chmod 755 from root recovery in OEM Linux and it didn't work. Then I tried chmod 755 / in root prompt again but generic Linux and it fixed it. I'm in. Thanks.

Technically speaking what does chmod 700 / do? It seems it locks the OS from being accessed by any user, even root. Why would such an option be available in Linux? Is there a time when it's called for?
