# What is the default permission to linux structure? I set permission 777 but I want to set defautl permission

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, directory-structure

I make a mistake, originally I set 777 permissions to all my root structure folder (I had a login loop), but I was able to change with 755 (root owner and root group).
For safety reasons, I would to set the default permissions to all root structure folder (with the right owner,group) for all folders and subfolders structure.

Here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPNO1.png

Someone can help me??

Thanks

Mitab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)

Answer (score 1):

"The default permissions for files on a Unix system are often 600 or 644 . Permissions of 600 mean that the owner has full read and write access to the file, while no other user can access the file."

Source: "https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/"

Edit: "For executable files, the equivalent settings would be 700 and 755 which correspond to 600 and 644 except with execution permission"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I can set 600 or 644 to all structure? What is the owner and group? Root or admin user? How I can identify the executable files?