# Jetson AGX Orin Backup without sudo cmd, no jetpack/sdkmanager

Tags: sudo

I made an error when trying to change file permissions. I did "sudo chmod 777 -R / " and now I can no longer use “sudo” because when I try, I get this “/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set”. I completely destroyed all file permissions and came to the conclusion that I have to backup and reinstall everything on a Jetson AGX Orin. Since I can’t download “sdkmanager” or “JetPack” without “sudo”, how should I proceed?

Comment: Reinstall the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if I accidentally run command "chmod -R" on system directories (/, /etc, ...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)